# Number, stand still! (aka don't move the top bar numbers while hovering over them)

Tags: feature-request, design, top-bar

Am I the only one finding the below annoying?

> [image]

I don't like things moving around, even when I hover over them. The previous top bar behavior was just fine, to highlight the number when hovering. Please bring it back, and don't move the number the way it's moving now.

Comment: *Am I the only one finding the below annoying?* Yes ....

Comment: I think the UI designer wanted to reveal some of the underlying icon when it is obscured by the number. When you smack stuff together you have not much other options.

Comment: @rene so they could make it appear higher to begin with.

Comment: In SO, it is already positioned a little higher position. here, the topbar height is lesser than that of SO. Seriously you have to use some other tool to make gif. This tool destroying small images with adding a label. What if the image you recorded is of 20x5, there is nothing other than the makeAgif label

Comment: @redhand and still it jumps to be even higher on SO. As for tool, don't have time to look, used the first thing I found. Luckily the label isn't hiding anything important. :)

Comment: “Am I the only one finding the below annoying?” [No, absolutely not!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week/343328#comment445002_343328) [This userstyle](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343830/make-the-indicator-of-unread-inbox-messages-more-visible/343948#343948) makes the number stay in place (among other things, and I haven't revised it yet for the non-SO variant).