# New top bar is live

Tags: discussion, top-bar, announcements

> **UPDATE:** TeamDAG has reviewed all of the feedback below and updated with status. We are actively working on fixes as time allows. Thanks to everyone who contributed constructive feedback.

We released the new top bar for all users across all communities. The only exceptions are Area 51 and chat. They will be coming a little later.

I wanted to take this opportunity to respond to some of the key pieces of feedback we received after the [initial post about the top bar coming to the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300829/new-top-bar-is-coming-to-the-stack-exchange-network). I'll try to summarize these feedback points below, say whether we are/aren't addressing each, and give you a short explanation why or why not.

### [Consistency between SO and SE network sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300875/354333)

**Concern:** Navigation links (questions, tags, users, etc.) are not folded into the top bar on SE network sites. The color of the top bar is different.

**Status:** [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

**Explanation:**
Navigation - In order to integrate navigation (as it is on SO) we would need to revisit each of the site themes and we don't have the resources for that now. We may revisit this in the future. But this would likely require reducing the level of theming that we support. The team believes that the current compromise results in a coherent design that users can understand, even if it isn't completely consistent.

Color - The top bar needs to be black on network sites, since that works best with the many themes. The SO top bar color was a branding decision and won't be changed to black.

### [Review queue icon sucks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355236/the-new-review-icon-isnt-an-improvement)

**Concern:** The review queue icon doesn't look anything like what I'd expect. It isn't recognizable. (note: this is actually a holdover from SO feedback).

**Status:** [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

**Explanation:** We are happy to change this icon to one that works better for everyone. We ran a survey for people to pick their top two favorite icons. Over 600 people participated. We are doing some additional design review on the top two candidates and will announce the results soon.

### [Review queue false positives](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300864/354333)

**Concern:** The review queue shouldn't "light up" or have the red dot when there are no items to review.

**Status:** [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

**Explanation:** We've squashed some bugs with the new design, but probably have a few more to deal with. We will continue on our bug stomping journey.

### [Add labels to icons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300872/354333)

**Concern:** Still, the icons aren't as recognizable as they should be. But if you add labels below them they would be. Please add labels.

**Status:** [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

**Explanation:** There is no room for legible labels in the current design. The font would have to be so small that it is arguable if it would help many people. (The [example posted to meta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opoIr.png) cheated a bit by changing "achievements" to the much shorter "awards".)

### [Stickiness global preference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300865/354333)

**Concern:** SO top bar is sticky by default with a preference to unstick it. Network site top bar is not sticky by default and there is no way to make it so. Can we get a global preference for setting stickiness across all sites?

**Status:** [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

**Explanation:** We think this is a good thing to have, now we just need to figure out how to make it so. This could be a somewhat expensive setting since we currently don't have any global settings. That said, we are actively investigating it.

### [Moderator tools are difficult to see/access](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300834/354333)

**Concern:** Inserting the mod tools to the far right (after the site switcher) creates confusion and make them difficult to see/interact with. Move them.

**Status:** [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

**Explanation:** We have moved these items to the left of the profile. This has the benefit of keeping the site switcher in the same location at all times. The new location for these tools has higher visibility. Also, we are going to continue investigating additional improvements for moderators.

### Search transition is confusing

**Concern:** When a user clicks into the search box it animates to expand. Stop it! It's annoying.

**Status:** [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

**Explanation:** This was needed on Stack Overflow where the search box can get very small due to space constraints. It isn't necessary on other sites and has been turned off.

### [Clickable Stack Exchange logo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300831/354333)

**Concern:** The Stack Exchange logo is useless. Clicking on it should trigger the site switcher (see below) or it should lead to stackexchange.com.

**Status:** [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

**Explanation:** This has been fixed. Clicking on the Stack Exchange logo will display a brief popup about the Stack Exchange network, and a link to stackexchange.com.

### [Site switcher](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300869/354333)

**Concern:** Moving the site switcher from the left to the right is confusing. Move it back.

**Status:** [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

**Explanation:** We know that this will take some getting use to, but based on previous experience with changes like this we are confident that everyone can make this adjustment.

### [Inaccessible color choices](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356382/change-the-color-of-the-achievements-icon-when-its-highlighted-for-users-wit)

**Concern:** Some designs choices are inaccessible for people with low vision or color blindness (specifically the green achievements icon for people with deuteranopia).

**Status:** [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

**Explanation:** We are undergoing a general evaluation of our accessibility and will fix issues as a part of that process.

### Where do we go from here

There are a number of other fixes that we made to address more minor issues or bugs in the top bar. So this list isn't exhaustive, but covers the biggest issues. Obviously there are some items that are still under work. We will continue working on them and listening for additional feedback on the new top bar.

Comment: Is anything going to be done about the different position of the red dot on the review icon? On SO it at the top right, but on other sites it's further down the icon. (I posted images in TL that I can dig out if you need example). Is this a side effect of the different topbar heights?

Comment: @chrisf We will take a look at this.

Comment: somewhat related: If stickiness becomes a global setting (or an optionally global?) can we also move some other settings into global scope like keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: @Vogel612'sShadow And the scope creep begins. ;) Seriously, we haven't started investigating this yet, be we will consider this when we start.

Comment: That's sad that's Help Center icon is now between the other sites icon and achievements with inbox, especially in that order. The achievements and inbox are opened quite often, other sites sometimes (for those who use them) and help center probably never (Or at least a lot more rare, when taking a tour and like that). They will mess up each other.

Comment: @MrZak You won't have the help dropdown at all on any site you have more than 500 reputation on. It will be review instead... Though, I'm not sure how I follow that having the help link there will mess things up. Could you explain that?

Comment: @MrZak As I said, you won't see it at all on Blender (the only site you have +500 rep) on. That means that newer users will have it at hand while experienced users will have the link to the review queues. :D

Comment: @MrZak So am I... you see it here because you have less than 500 reputation. I have no Help Center link in the top bar.

Comment: What about putting the site logo and shortened site name in the topbar?

Comment: It works well. Why bother changing it? Please put an option of reverting to the older version so that old dogs like me are happy.

Comment: @JoeFriend I suppose area51 won’t be concerned by the new top bar in any cases… isn’t it ?

Comment: @JF that would damage the designs of many sites (SF&F, Worldbuilding, Mi Yodeya, to name a few).  Also, I briefly used a userscript to put the site logo into the topbar instead of the SE logo and found that many site logos look *terrible* on a black background.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I'm not sure what the "that" is referring to in your first sentence.

Comment: @JoeFriend sorry, I was referring to JF's suggestion to put the site logo and shortened name in the topbar.  That would mean that the logo would no longer be incorporated into the larger designs we have now -- or I suppose it could end up duplicated in the topbar *and* the site header design, but I assumed the designers wouldn't do that.  A topbar short enough to be useful is too short to reflect designs like Worldbuilding's.  We love our design and would be very sad if somebody broke it.

Comment: By the looks of it, you've either missed or rejected [my suggestion to shrink the search bar a little](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301069/285368). Can this please be fixed? It's a glaring issue, especially due to the tiny SE logo right next to it.

Comment: The nav bar is ok, I would switch dev efforts to other things as Ask question interface etc

Comment: @Joe Firend Awesome! It's great to see You guys keep constantly improving and taking feedback into consideration! Keep up the good work :)

Comment: Thanks for posting the survey about the icon. There doesn't seem to be a way to specify "I only think one of these is a good choice, and want to abstain on a second vote", so I haven't completed it.

Comment: Typo: "visability" under mod tools.

Comment: "SO top bar color was a branding decision" so the marketing department is now in charge of UX. Fine, I give up, I'll resort to userscripts to work around whatever they come up with. But reading stuff like that makes me cynical.

Comment: @PetterFriberg See my TeamDAG project update for the other things we're working on including Ask a Question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301449/teamdag-project-updates/301450#301450

Comment: As a mod please *please* do not make the review icon a flag button.

Comment: @JoeFriend, where should we direct requests about implementation on stackexchange.com, Area 51, and chat?  (I have a specific use case for the first of those that would be negatively affected by applying the current top-bar there, so I'd like the chance to raise it before it's too late.)  Thanks for keeping us in the loop!

Comment: @MonicaCellio You can create a new post if you'd like and link to it here.

Comment: Seems that the bar is working ok as per my experience. Just wondering why isn't the bar static (fixed when you scroll) like on SO?

Comment: @GrayCygnus See "Stickiness global preference" item in the post above.

Comment: @petermortenson Clearly I need to hire you as my editor. ;)

Comment: @JoeFriend Thanks, I think it would be a great idea, as one would not have to scroll all the way up in the middle of reading answers or questions, to interact with the bar (respond to mentions, see achievement changes, do reviews, mod options, etc.)

Comment: I hate this so much. I've clicked the left top icon a dozen times today.

Comment: The new top bar seems to think my name is "false" rather than Richard. Also, the left edge of the bronze badge icon is slightly cropped.

Comment: Move site switcher from most right side to most left side (with the existing logo).

Comment: @Richard - that's from the SOX userscript, which has broken rather drastically.

Comment: Search widths across sites are incorrect. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357658/search-bar-widths-across-the-sites

Comment: @Mithrandir - Turning off SOX means that my username is missing entirely. That's sort of an improvement

Comment: @Richard That's how the new top bar is supposed to look. It doesn't show username except in a tooltip.

Comment: @called2voyage - Which is dumb. If I sign in with multiple accounts (work / personal), how do I know at a glance which account I'm using?

Comment: @Richard Though allowed (with limitations) multiple accounts are not officially supported: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277435/228367

Comment: @Richard Plus, you could always make sure your user image is markedly different with each account.

Comment: @called2voyage - Hmm. Or perhaps they could have just not broken it in the first place.

Comment: Could you comment on [un-bolding the rep number](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301036/172958)? It's trivial to implement and mane people appear to agree it would be much less distracting.

Comment: "The SO top bar color was a branding decision and won't be changed to black." Why not? It's not universal if one site is different.

Comment: Also, please don't bury the review icon survey in a random place in a Meta post somewhere and only have it up "for a day or two". Make an announcement for the whole network, and tell them exactly how long it will remain open for.

Comment: @TylerH We don't need everyone to fill out the survey, so it doesn't need to be super high profile. We just need a sampling to figure out which icon(s) resonate most with folks. We already have over 300 responses which is probably more than enough. That said, we will leave it open until tomorrow afternoon.

Comment: Please demonstrate or explain, on each of the 171 SE sites,  how each site and its users can get "used to" (transition to) the current top bar. There are valid questions (see answers here) about  deleted immediate access to features that existed until less than 12 hours ago.  About design, about placement and reversals. There is also an awful lot of feedback and concerns...

Comment: ... (cont.) Does  the process: (creation of a new design, evaluation, improvements, etc, then implementation for a small fraction of all to-be-affected-users as a "test," feedback analysis, tweaking, and then today, Implementation-net-work-wide implementation), include an additional feedback loop, so all users, network wide, can weigh in the the changes? If not, why not?

Comment: @WhyNought Yes we are still open to feedback. You can post it here.

Comment: @amWhy Could you please add an option for "none of these"? Personally, none of the options speak to me. The thing that tells me what it is is the red circle.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking of me, @SteveBennett.  I do not understand to what comment specifically you are replying to. I certainly never set out to make an exhaustive list of concerns/complaints, if that's what you mean.  Please read the last sentence in my second second comment above this post.

Comment: @JoeFriend [here's the new post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301923/162102) about the network profile.  Thanks for considering.

Comment: *`Review queue icon sucks`* and the associated poll: ew. I only like *one* of them (#5, lower center) and was forced to pick a second. I went with #4 (lower left), which would've been like....my fifth choice (with the other four being sixteenth through thirtieth).

Comment: Sorry amWhy, replied to wrong person. I meant @JoeFriend: could you please add a "none of the above" option to the poll?

Comment: Personally, I don't see how losing the count of items awaiting review is helpful. To be perfectly clear it's a detriment.

Comment: I can't get to the meta sites anymore through the top bar when I'm on a sub-site, I used to click on the drop down but it isn't there anymore when I'm on a sub-site like EE.SE. The only way to get to the meta is through my profile. Super annoying

Comment: @laptop2d The meta for the site you're on is linked to in the site switcher.

Comment: @JoeFriend The one in the top left? There is no drop down for me when I am on a sub site like [EE.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/). When I go back to the meta, the drop down reappears, when I go back to EE.SE the drop down disappears and I cannot access the meta for EE.SE. I can't access anything, there is no drop down, clicking on the button takes me back to https://stackexchange.com/ Even on this page there is no drop down for me

Comment: @laptop2d Site switcher has switched on SO.com and all Q&A sites. It's on the far right. SE.com will be updated later (along with Area 51 and chat).

Comment: @JoeFriend That was confusing, well at least I know where it is now.

Comment: Non cheated label suggestion: **achiev.**

Comment: Noooooooooooooo!!!!!!! I don't like the new top bar!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: About the position of site switcher, you say: "We know that this will take some getting use to, but based on previous experience with changes like this we are confident that everyone can make this adjustment": No, this adjustment is annoying also because in the Android app the site switcher is on the left, and one should continuously switch between the two positions.

Comment: Why can't the review queue icon be something like a magnifying glass?

Comment: Great. Link to script that puts it back the way it was, please.

Comment: No one really uses meta anyways.

Comment: @Mazura It's [just below on this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301909)

Comment: @JoeFriend I've asked for this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302093/please-dont-red-alert-me-for-queues-ive-handled

Comment: @ICanHazUpvotzPleez: There wasn't enough moved cheese this year. SO devs have a very strict quota, and if they don't meet it, they don't get a yearly bonus.

Comment: Top answer says we don't like it. Edit: "New top bar is live. If you don't like it, click [HERE." (link to script)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301909/255297)

Comment: Nevermind. On refresh, I do get hovertips. Don't know what was going on before.

Comment: @Mego looks like you forgot to award the bounty?

Comment: @ICan it's all because of Stack Overflow. The top bar there is used for navigation as well, i.e. the tabs which appear on all sites below the top bar (Questions, Tags, Users) are part of the top bar in Stack Overflow. So they needed something new, and reduce size of all other parts of the top bar. And since Stack Overflow is part of Stack Exchange network, they couldn't leave it with a totally different top bar. The result is ugly hybrid, no doubt, but at least they tried. Think it's all explained in some MSO discussion, probably in the top bar introduction there.

Comment: On a side note, looks like @JoeFriend "gave up" on us, and not responding to feedback anymore. Last comment 6 days ago, and there are dozens of comments which need his attention. Oh well, we'll survive. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard There's still 2 days left. I intend to leave it up for the full count.

Comment: @Mego oh, from the bounty reason and description looked like you meant it for one specific answer.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I do intend to award it to that specific answer. But I also want it to be up for the full week to draw attention to the fact that the new top bar sucks, and that there is a userscript to revert most of the terrible changes.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks for the concern. My family and I have been sick for the past four days. The team is still reading and evaluating the feedback (this post and several others). In fact we are meeting to discuss today. We will be responding, but probably not point by point due to volume.

Comment: @JoeFriend sorry to hear! Best wishes and quick recovery to you and your family then, and glad the feedback is being noticed.

Comment: The **chat**.SE place still has the top left _StackExchange_ drop down menu, which makes it extremely confusing. At least change the bar there to maintain uniformity or take the top right part of the redesigned bar to top left of the chat pages

Comment: I stopped using StackOverflow after introducing new topbar because it's irritating, uncomfortable and counter-intuitive. Now it seems that I'm going to stop using all other SE sites.

Comment: @WiccanKarnak chat, Area51, and stackexchange.com all have only a "copy" of the top bar, code-wise. It's delicate job for the developers, and they don't want to copy something which is still bugged. I prefer they wait until all dust settles down and only then copy the top bar. TL;DR: 6-8 weeks.

Comment: "There is no room for legible labels in the current design." One could just change the current design to make room for legible labels.

Comment: I'm pretty much ready to give up on SO. You keep changing the layout, adding pointless features and making the site hard to use. How about a little consistency and UX? Failing that, just listen to the feedback you're getting. If the site design is too cramped to have proper labels, that doesn't mean nobody needs labels, it means the latest iteration of your design is inadequate.

Comment: Another reason this is horrible. It's too wide to fit on my netbook screen. So I have to scroll to the right to select the site switcher. While the useless link in the top left corner, which is accessible without scrolling, sits glaring at me stupidly,

Comment: @OrganicMarble I'm confused by your comment. The top bar is responsive and shrinks down to a very small size. ([see screenshot](https://cl.ly/3r2o1Q1u1d2N/Image%202017-10-30%20at%208.04.57%20AM.png)).

Comment: Not on my Linux netbook/Midori browser.  Will post screenshot when I get on reasonable wifi.

Answer (score 307):

> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - we implementd a content bubble that explains the network and a links to the SE.com front page. Something like [Robotnik's idea](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301922/354333).

I don't think linking the Stack Exchange logo in the top left to the stackexchange.com site is an improvement, it's worse than the old inactive version.

For a new user that has never seen the old site, the expectation for clicking on the site logo would likely be that it takes them to the homepage itself. This is not the case here, it takes them to an entirely different site they never saw before.

The SE network is complicated, but that complication is not something we should inflict on just anyone careless enough to click on the logo in the top left.

For established users, muscle memory alone will mean lots of users clicking on that icon expecting to open the site switcher. Changing the behavior of a UI element that existed for years at that specific place, and really looks the same is incredibly confusing. Making that UI element do nothing at all is terrible UX, but making it do something that is the wrong thing most of the time is even worse.

With the rate of updates stackexchange.com receives, I don't have the impression that SE cares all that much about it. So why would you want to lead a large number of users to a site that isn't all that useful to most users, and is not really maintained well anyway?

Comment: Yes, I hate that it doesn't become the site switcher...=(

Comment: Could we at least have a tool tip telling what we get when we click the logo? That would alleviate the problem to some extent.

Comment: Hmm... Is the linked page stackexchange.com even useful to users? Do people want to go there so often that it warrants such a visible link? (I don't know. This is a genuine question.)

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Tag filters are a pretty useful, if a bit neglected feature for users that are active on many different SE sites. I'm not sure how many people except me actually use them though.

Comment: The confusing part for me is that the stackexchange nav bar still has the site switcher on the right, er, left, and the logo is _identical_ to the version used on the new nav bar. Its now a waste of space with no real function except subverting the expectations of the users who click on it expecting a site switcher from years of muscle memory. They could have at least changed the logo, too.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Not true, I often utilize stackexchange.com to leaf through cross-site information.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yes, I visit stackexchange.com nearly every day. I use it to see the full queue of Hot Network Questions, I click my network profile page to go through my recent activity across multiple sites, etc.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta From a network perspective it makes sense for the Stack Exchange logo to link to a central page from which you can view an overview of the networked sites.

Comment: I really hate the stackexchange button (even if I've only seen it for a few minutes)!

Comment: @called2voyage Clicking on the "Hot Network Questions" title on the right-sidebar also goes there, the only way I use to get to it

Comment: @Izkata I know, I used to use that to get there too. Makes sense if you know to look for HNQ, but if you're a new user looking for the central page of the network it is a rather unintuitive place to look. Also, depending on screen layout, sometimes you have to scroll to get to that link.

Comment: I actually strongly disagree - that Stack Exchange says "Stack Exchange".  I would expect it to go to stackexchange.com.  I do not believe clicking on it and expecting to go to, say, worldbuilding.stackexchange.com, is intuitive at all.  I think the primary issue people have with it is that it's not the site switcher anymore (yet looks exactly the same), not that the link goes to *exactly where it says it will go*.

Comment: You know what's *extra confusing?* That same logo in the same place *at the stackexchange.com homepage* **is the site switcher.**

Comment: To be clear, for @JoeFriend: this is not merely a matter of change avoidance, getting confused or muscle memory. It's a matter of having a big important element do nothing or something frankly irrelevant, and having a new element, confusingly similar to the big element, do something I use all the time. Why give so much priority going to a frankly irrelevant site where the site switcher is way more important to navigate the network? The UX seems wrong (and since it's UX, it *is* therefore wrong).

Comment: [This proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301922/162102) solves the problems raised in this answer while preserving SE's intent to do something (other than the site switcher) with that space.

Comment: Currently, the link serves no useful purpose whatsoever. There is nothing useful in the destination page. At all. (It may be *interesting* to see questions being added in real time, or questions the system deems "hot" using its faulty algorithm, but you don't need a link for it. Especially when that link used to do something *completely* different.)

Comment: @Ajean That is a fair point. But in that case I think they should change stackexchange.com to something else entirely. It doesn't make sense to me that the logo links to a page of the top posts across the network. They should move the top posts to a different page like stackexchange.com/hot-network-questions

Comment: @KodosJohnson I can agree with that!  The content of stackexchange.com does leave something do be desired...

Comment: @AndrewLeach the "useful" purpose is there. It's encouraging users to visit other sites, becoming emotionally invested in questions and answers and therefore joining the site because it's absurdly easy to have forty accounts. The higher the number of members per site, the greater the "stats" appeal for advertisers. Everyone has, and will, click on that awful SE logo thinking they will go back to the site's main page. It's a cunning trap/bait.

Comment: @Draco18s What's even more confusing is that (a simplified version of) the same logo in the same place is the site switcher on the **mobile sites**.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I don't use it, but I've seen some comments to that regard.

Comment: Is it wrong of me that my use case in changing stack is now to click the "Stack Exchange" logo to get to the main site, then click it again to get the site switcher because the main site doesn't have the new toolbar...

Comment: @canon except that the search bar right next to that logo contains the current site name (e.g. "Search on Electronic Engineering") which makes the top bar and hence logo part of the current stack navigation.

Comment: Totally agree, I keep accidentally clicking on the blinking thing

Comment: @Mari-LouA As is so often the case, I find your analysis here spot-on (i.e., It is indeed "a cunning trap/bait").  [This related {possible duplicate?} question {post}](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323008/a-term-for-creating-internet-traffic) and OP's mention of "branding decision[s]" says it all.

Comment: The new site switcher location is so bad that I simply *thought it was removed* for weeks before finding out here that there's a button for it in the upper right. And the "clickable logo" takes a bit of prime real-estate that used to do something useful, and replaces it with a link to stackexchange.com, which is nothing more than HNQ writ large, making it not just useless, but **worse** than useless.

Answer (score 127):

#### Consistency between SO and SE network sites

> In order to integrate navigation (as it is on SO) we would need to revisit each of the site themes and we don't have the resources for that now.

So align SO with the rest of the network!

#### Review queue icon sucks

> We are happy to change this icon to one that works better for everyone.

I took your survey, but it's missing an option for “they all suck”. I picked the ones that sucked marginally less (at least, it shows that you're capable on improving on the current icon), but I have a better proposal:

[image: review icon proposal]

I'm fairly confident that most people will figure out what that button does pretty quickly.

#### Review queue false positives

> The review queue shouldn't "light up" or have the red dot when there are no items to review. (…) We've squashed some bugs with the new design

This is not a design problem. We've had long discussions of how to improve the review counts. Why has the only response from SE been to remove numbers and expound on how it's infeasible to get the information to be correct all of the time, rather than explore solutions to make the information correct most of the time?

#### Add labels to icons

> There is no room for legible labels in the current design.

You could remove the icons that don't look anything like what they do (the square bra, the scratch pad, the speech bubble). That would save room.

#### Search transition is confusing

> This was needed on Stack Overflow

No, it isn't. Just give SO the same top bar as the rest of the network. Problem solved.

#### Clickable Stack Exchange logo

> The Stack Exchange logo is useless. (…) Clicking on the Stack Exchange logo will open stackexchange.com in a new tab.

So instead of doing nothing, it does something nobody uses? What's the point?

#### Site switcher

> we are confident that everyone can make this adjustment

Sure. But why change in the first place? Are you going to flip every couple of years?

Comment: "*I took your survey, but it's missing an option for “they all suck”*" - I thought this sounded pretty harsh, but having looked at the survey, I have to admit you're right. (A *flag* icon for review? Seriously?! How confusing is *that* going to be, since flags and reviews are almost completely separate parts of the SE system?)

Comment: @Randal'Thor To be honest, we didn't think the flag was right. But hey, icons are hard and we've been wrong before.

Comment: *"So instead of doing nothing, it does something nobody uses"* As I see it wasn't doing anything due to fixed bug, but it's now doing opening stackexchange site. The meaning of this action is indeed quite disputed

Comment: [If you cannot immediately think of the *right* icon, chances are that you shouldn’t be using an icon](http://uxmyths.com/post/715009009/myth-icons-enhance-usability). [“The best icon is a text label”](https://thomasbyttebier.be/blog/the-best-icon-is-a-text-label).

Comment: I agree with "why change [the site switcher] in the first place?". It was there, we figured it out, it's not functionally like anything else on the right (which is all notifications), there's still a thing where it was and there's been back and forth about what it should even do -- it should do site switching.

Comment: Funny, the flag was the only one of the six that I thought made any sense at all. Although the main point in its favor is that its shape is clearly distinguishable from the other icons.

Comment: "explore solutions to make the information correct most of the time?" ←Yes. Yes. Yes. So much yes.

Comment: In what way are "flags and reviews ... almost completely separate parts of the SE system"? The primary way that a post gets into the review queues is in response to a flag. Are there other types of flags? Yes, but only moderators need to concern themselves with that. It doesn't dilute the powerfulness of the metaphor for regular users. Not to mention what Josh Caswell said, about that being the only distinctive icon that doesn't have three horizontal lines. @rand

Comment: @CodyGray “The primary way that a post gets into the review queues is in response to a flag” Not really. Suggested edits, first posts and reopen are never fueled by flags. Plus a flag icon looks like this is about *raising* flags, not about *handling* flags, because this is what the flag icon means everywhere else on the site (and on all the sites I can remember where I've seen a similar icon, except the ones where it's about language and locale preferences).

Comment: ^ Like @Gilles summarises it's definitely a UX problem to have an icon that means two things (or two nearly identical icons that mean two different things). The flag icon is used to raise flags, so I'd expect a flag button to be something I use to make reports — it's how I view those buttons on any other site I use, so I expect it'd be how people not expert at this site (like those of us talking here) would see such a button.

Comment: Hmm. I've never seen a flag icon on any other site, and I don't know where else Stack Overflow uses a flag icon like that, other than on comments. I'm not seeing the confusion. I understand the concern that it is about *handling* flags, not *raising* flags. On the other hand, it's not about clipboards, or checkmarks, or horizontal lines, either. They're all metaphors, and they're all imperfect. If you keep reducing the metaphor, you just make it less distinctive and less mnemonic. I *instantly* recognized the flag icon as relating to flagged posts. Huge improvement over the other choices.

Comment: I agree with the sentiment that the flag is a wrong choice, but the other options were *objectively worse.* The pen writing wordlines (inside a speech bubble) does not look like "review" to me (or anyone) and ***FOUR*** of the survey options were variations on that theme.  ***FOUR.***

Comment: @Draco18s Uh? Only one of the six has something that looks remotely like a pen to me. Did we get different choices? I got the same as [David](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301891). I picked the two that have check marks. A check mark does kind of convey review: you're asked (whether) to approve something.

Comment: @Gilles I made the comment before finding the reference David posted (although I did attempt to go look at the designs first). Yes, only one has a pen, but all four have "wordlines in a speechbubble" (except 1, where it's a clipboard and 3, which lacks it). *None* of which say "review" to me.

Comment: @Draco18s 1, 3 and 4 are surely not speech bubbles. I think 4 is supposed to be a clipboard as well, but I'm not sure. It's the check mark that makes it look like “review” to me. A bare check mark wouldn't work because it would look like “review the current page”, but a check mark with something else kind of works for me once I know what it's about.

Comment: @Gilles Try 1, 3, and 6. #4 clearly doesn't have "wordlines" and isn't one of the four I'm referring to. And I already stated that #1 has the speechbubble replaced by a clipboard and #3 has it removed. But other than that, those four are virtually identical and clear variations on the icon we already have (which has been identified as being bad).

Comment: I have poor vision and a lot of trouble with low contrast GUI elements. The dark gray on black icons such a the review queue icon are nearly invisible to me. When the new top bar came up on Mathematica.SE this week, for several minutes I thought the site had malfunctioned and that I was locked out of the revue queue. I also don't like the dark gray icons because they give the impression that they are disabled (i.e., grayed out). I request the gray be considerably lightened -- all the way to white would be good.

Comment: +1 especially for "No, it isn't. Just give SO the same top bar as the rest of the network. Problem solved." That reason given for the top bar makes no sense. You have an average feature and a mediocre feature, you want to keep one feature, so you should replace the mediocre feature with the average feature, not the other way round. Of course, assuming you cannot improve the average feature.

Comment: I think you should have posted each of your points as separate answers. I agree with some of them and disagree with others, so I don't know whether to upvote or to downvote.

Answer (score 99):

I don't like many of the things about the new top-navigation. Thus, I wrote a userscript which allows you to adjust the top-navigation to the way that you want it.

#### The user script is: [Top-navigation choices](//stackapps.com/q/7603).

You can set preferences for how you want the new top-navigation to look. It works on all sites with the new navigation. There's:

- Move drop-down buttons (left, right, center)
- Adjust height
- Global sticky/not sticky top-nav
- Add a dark theme (top-nav) for SO/MSO
- Merge the site-switcher with the logo
- and more.

Everything's optional. You can have the top-nav look the way you want.

By default, on MSE it looks like:

[image: Default is this]

Drop-down menu buttons can be centered:

[image: Centered drop-down buttons and light theme]

Here are the options in action:

[image: Various options settings]

Comment: @Cœur, The [option to add labels to the drop-down menu icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8aBv.png) will be in the next version of the script.

Comment: So so so so so glad I found this. +100

Comment: A review counter would be really nice to have!

Comment: @ElderGeek, I'm going to need a bit more detail as to what you're requesting. From what you stated, I assume you mean a number badge on the review icon indicating the number of reviews which are currently in (some?, all?) queues. Is that correct? While something like that would be possible, there's no direct way to access that information from the SE API (to the best of my knowledge). Thus, a hack of some sort would be necessary to obtain the information (various possibilities).

Comment: I can live with the minor cosmetic changes. What I wasn't having was the arbitrary rearranging of the locations and uses of the buttons. This puts them back where they were, and do what they did. Thank you.

Comment: @Mazura What I'm looking for is what we used to have, which if I'm not mistaken was the count awaiting review in the review queue with the highest number posts awaiting review. (This has always been the close vote queue in my experience). Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: Dec 14 update for Greasemonkey broke the script? (running XP)

Answer (score 82):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Thank you very much for this followup.  I know you have a near-thankless job, so here's some thanks to offset that.

On "Clickable Stack Exchange logo", you wrote:

> Explanation: This has been fixed. Clicking on the Stack Exchange logo will open stackexchange.com in a new tab.

All of that sounds fine except the last four words.  Opening the link in a new tab is inconsistent with almost everything else on SE.  (We don't even open Hot Network Questions in a new tab, and that's about as "not this current site" as you can get.)  A new tab for the logo is therefore surprising and ends up being pretty disruptive.  I wrote more about this in [this late answer to the earlier announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301755/162102) (sorry, didn't know this update was coming or I'd've waited).

Please open the link in the *current* tab.  It's what users expect on SE.  People who want a new tab have an easy way to get one; people who don't have no easy way to avoid getting one.

Comment: Agreed! The fact that they ended up making it open in a new tab is actually a sign that the target address is something a user will likely not expect, so linking to SE is probably the wrong choice anyway (as per [Mad Scientists’s answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301845/new-top-bar-next-steps-and-response-to-feedback#301848))

Comment: Looks like this has been changed; clicking the StackExchange logo in the new top bar opens `stackexchange.com` in the current tab as of present.

Comment: We made this change last night, and are considering removing the link and the rest of Mad Scientist's answer above :)

Comment: Thanks @Kasra!  I'll mark this status-completed.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi If you'll take my opinion, I think most of the backlash to it linking to stackexchange.com is not really an issue with the link as much as it is a knee-jerk reaction from people missing the site switcher in that location. Of course, I'm biased because I'm the one who suggested to link it to stackexchange.com in the first place.

Comment: No, please don't naviagte to anywhere in any tab. Open the site switcher.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I think that battle is lost.  Now I'm trying to contain collateral damage.

Comment: In *that* case, have it not do anything. If it needs to be there at all. I'd far rather it doesn't do anything than it does something which I positively don't want (like go the HNQ list -- what use is that?).

Comment: @sumelic Currently, it serves no useful purpose whatsoever. There is nothing useful in the destination page. At all. (It may be *interesting* to see questions being added in real time, or questions the system deems "hot" using its faulty algorithm, but you don't a link for it. Especially when that link used to do something *completely* different.)

Comment: @AndrewLeach, sumelic, could we relocate the discussion of whether it should link to SE *at all* to [this answer that suggests removing that link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301848/162102)? It'll be more likely to be seen by the right people there.  This answer was meant to focus on the new-tab problem.  Thanks.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Yes, sorry. I've already upvoted that one. I suppose my last comment here might be useful there.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi - I feel [my proposal for the button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301922/179041) offers a 'best of both worlds' solution, so if you're considering removing the link function entirely, could you take a look there first? :-)

Answer (score 62):

> [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) — The site switcher, in its current iteration, has been on SO.com for 8 months or so and on all other sites for about a month. We will leave the icon, location and behavior as is for now. We will reconsider how it works in the context of the information architecture investigation mentions in the [November TeamDAG update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/302969/321340).

I risk [repeating myself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300869/321340), but the site switcher symbol is confusing.
I can (grudgingly) live with it being where it is now, but I still often mistake the symbol for chat.
The drop down menu contains a chat link so I do eventually get what I expect, but I have hard time finding the site switcher.
The tooltip helps, but I would recommend exploring new ideas for the symbol.
I know symbols are hard, but could we at least see and discuss some options?

**Comment to the status update:**
Thanks for the update!
I am glad to see that this is being seriously considered instead of throwing in a thoughtless quick fix.
However, I would prefer to have some sort of short term solution too, but I admit I have nothing up my sleeve to offer, apart from a community discussion of options.

Comment: this! a thousand times this! who sees a speech bubble and thinks "site switcher"?

Comment: Getting to "meta" is hard.  It is like they don't want new folks to engage in leadership, or helping in anything like an administrative capacity.

Comment: I'd love to have both meta and chat clickable icons. Now there is no direct link to meta and chat main pages.

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo agreed.. getting to both meta and chat has always been a bit more convoluted then it needed to be and the latest update seems to have continued this. TBH I generally get to meta by clicking on one of the "FEATURED ON META" links and navigating from there and as for chat I generally just type the fricking URL. Both of which are nuts if you think about it.

Comment: @motosubatsu The site switcher has links to both.

Comment: @JoeFriend sweet! a little embarrassing that I never noticed that tbh, but every day's a school day!

Comment: @JoeFriend I had also missed that.

Comment: I actually had to read it here to even find out that there was a site switcher. I clicked on the "StackExchange" and then there was a site switcher at the expected place, but of course not with the site-specific meta in it. Really a bad change.

Answer (score 44):

## RE: Clickable StackExchange Logo

> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - we implemented a content bubble that explains the network and a links to the SE.com front page. Something similar to your idea below.

I do like the new top bar and I think it's a net-positive change, but I feel like the experience when clicking the Stack Exchange button is a bit jarring. While I definitely like that this now does *something*, I think immediately jumping away from the current Q&A site to stackexchange.com might be a bit weird for all users involved:

- New/Inexperienced/Single-site users find it jarring to end up somewhere else other than the current site they're on.
- Experienced/Multi-site users that regularly used the old dropdown now click it and end up on a different site immediately, when this likely wasn't their intended action.

I think the addition of a simple dropdown that explains what the Stack Exchange network is (say, the Mission Statement from the [Tour](https://stackexchange.com/tour)?), with links off to the website proper and the Tour itself would be helpful, *and* act as a 'buffer' to the navigation to help alleviate some confusion. So imagine this, in dropdown form:

<kbd>**Stack Exchange ▾**</kbd>

> Stack Exchange is a network of 170 communities that are created and run by experts and enthusiasts like you who are passionate about a specific topic. We build libraries of high-quality questions and answers, focused on each community's area of expertise.
>
> <kbd>**Visit Stack Exchange**</kbd>                                                                                                   [<kbd>**Take the Tour**</kbd>](https://stackexchange.com/tour)

This is just a suggestion but I'd be interested in hearing some feedback - What do you think?

Comment: Best idea I've heard yet.

Comment: This is pretty cool. That's a rather meaningful purpose to having that link at all. (Granted I expect I'll see people complaining "ugh now I'm clicking the thing and getting the network intro!" :D)

Comment: That would be good compromise, surely better than what we have now. :)

Comment: Oh, I love this idea. It makes the link do something, that something is consistent with what you might expect, and it actually does something useful and not invasive.

Comment: This is a great idea. I like the site switcher being with the other dropdowns (inbox, achievements, review), but I don't like that a button that used to be a dropdown now takes you to a different site just like that and I don't either like having a button that does nothing. This is a good way of keeping the site switcher consistent with the other dropdowns but still making the Stack Exchange button do something useful.

Answer (score 35):

> Updated with status tags to identify the various requests and which we are trying to address and those we aren't.

I thought I'd get used to the new top bar. I tried, really. But I was wrong. I can't get used to it.

It's worse than what we had before, in all aspects:

1. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) I keep clicking the SE logo to the left, close the new tab, sigh, and click the hamburger site switcher.
2. [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) I still can't really tell which icon is what, until something lights up. If I want to see inbox or reputation changes I usually end up clicking the wrong icon, go *arrgh* and click the other one.
3. [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) I never see the review icon lights up here on MSE even when there are some items. I sometimes click it anyway, see some grey review queues and wonder why they won't cause the icon itself to indicate this.

I am well aware this will not be changed. It can't be fixed.
This won't make me leave or rage quit, but it's just something annoying that is always there.

However, I'm afraid many long-time users will be even more annoyed and reduce their time on the sites or even quit. Stack Exchange will suffer a big hit. Not fatal, but losing many active users is very bad, especially on smaller sites.

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) **For the sake of those users, and myself, can we please have the option to revert back to the "old" top bar?** 
Like there is the option on Stack Overflow to switch between "new nav" and "old nav", there can be such option added to preferences on all sites. (Note: this isn't relevant for Stack Overflow, where the top bar is totally different.)

Comment: The firs thing I did when Youtube changed to their new design was turn on the dark theme and think, "that looks cool" - the second thing I did was find the button to revert back to the old design.

Comment: @X-27 There's a button to change YouTube back!? Where!?

Comment: @Draco18s probably it was for limited time, then if enough users reverted they would have nuked the new design... :)

Comment: A rant with no reasons isn't very helpful to the team to know what to fix for you. I know you say it can't be fixed but adding explanations of what you don't like and why helps everyone in the long run. I doubt you'll get the old bar back or even an option to revert back so you might as well try and improve the new one.

Comment: I agree with @TheLethalCoder, I'd be interested to see you describe what seems wrong about the new bar and what you preferred in the old bar. That can present actionable courses of improvement, and could prompt actual change where a call to revert it won't.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder valid request, edited.

Comment: @doppelgreener see edit.

Comment: Even accessing a sister-site meta via the hamburger logo is trickier than ever, how will newcomers find it? It's not intuitive at all.

Comment: @Mari that is actually not really an issue, users with less than 500 rep get a question mark icon, which opens the familiar help menu.

Comment: #1 I agree but that's something users need to get used to apparently. #2 They should really add the text to the icons but seem reluctant to do so. #3 A bug, think it's been reported elsewhere. Overall though your concerns aren't un-fixable so it doesn't seem as bad as you initially made out.

Comment: And then 500K users no longer see the question mark. Sometimes one really good answer gives the author two, three, or even five hundred rep, but the user will still be a newcomer. No, meta should always be visible, IMO.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Well, apparently I was never offered the choice. It was forced on me and I could find no way to change it back.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think you mean 500, not 500K. Not many users with 500k rep are newcomers or one-shot wonders ;-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I'm a mod with over 150k network-wide rep, and it took me a minute or two to work out how to get to meta today. From now on I'll probably go there mostly by just manually changing the URL (which is *also* more difficult than it used to be, btw, now that you have to put `meta` somewhere in the middle rather than at the start).

Comment: @Randal'Thor to he honest I used to switch to meta using the site switcher long before the change.

Comment: @Draco18s If you were logged in to your youtube account, and you clicked on your icon in the top right corner, there was a button that said, "restore old youtube" (I have no idea if it is still there, but that is how I was able to put it back).

Comment: @X-27 Aw yiss, OldTube is back. See, I wouldn't have thought of clicking on that because that button

Comment: To turn off the irritating SE Logo, I have created the file `chrome/userContents.css` in my Firefox profile directory with the rules `.top-bar .-logo {
  display: none !important;
}`

Comment: @ccorn then I would always look for it. Lol.

Comment: [This script on Stackapps](https://stackapps.com/questions/7603/top-navigation-choices) returns some of the old functionality. If you think it lacks something, you could always fork it

Comment: @TheLethalCoder *[...] but seem reluctant to do so.* This. They are human and are invested in their pet redesign project. Regardless of the userbase' reception of change, they're not going throw the new top bar out of the window. This *does* make some problems unfixable, thankfully a userscript to get the old bar back is available.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP The problem isn't that the bar is unfixable, it's that the things that need fixing aren't being done. I like the bar but it has major issues that can be fixed, they just aren't being.

Answer (score 34):

> [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) The primary CTA in this situation is "Join". We previously tested it in various locations and far right was the best. So we will keep the current order.

The switch switcher gets shunted aside by the "Join this community" button on sites I haven't joined:

[image]

It would make more sense to swap these two because:

1. The switch switcher is on the far right everywhere else, and
2. The "join this community" button would replace the other community-related icons (review, rep, etc.).

---

On another note, please don't hide the inbox on sites I haven't joined. I should be able to check notifications from sites I have joined whilst browsing sites I haven't joined.

---

For now I'm using these Stylish rules:

```css
#custom-header, .-container .-main, .-ctas {
    /* Nuke the Ubuntu custom top bar, the SE logo and the "join" button */
    display: none;
}

#search {
    padding-left: 0;
}

.js-top-bar {
    /* Keep the top bar on top, force black for AU */
    width: 100%;
    position: sticky;
    background-color: black;

}

.top-bar~.container {
    /* Remove the extra padding for the site header */
    margin-top: 0;
}

.top-bar .my-profile .-rep {
    /* rep count needn't be bold */
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

The top bar is now, AFAICT, consistent across SE sites.

Comment: Oh, ouch, I hadn't noticed that one yet. That's really bad: if I reflexively click at the location where every other site puts the site switched, I'd end up clicking to *join the community*! If I haven't joined a site, there's a reason. This is awful clickbait.

Comment: +1 being to the left of all those buttons (or, just the two buttons, really) would make more sense, including visually. It'd feel better seeing the two things always stuck to the right still be stuck there, and the button taking up the remaining extra space to their left.

Comment: @muru I logged a bug on this and we are investigating.

Comment: @JoeFriend there is a [popular feature request for this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302000/join-community-button-on-the-wrong-side-of-the-site-switcher) as well. 35 upvotes here, 13 there... no chance to reconsider the decision? Who decided "far right was the best"? I think the actual people using the sites are better in judging that than even some external UX experts, in case you are using those.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The decision wasn't driven by external UX experts. We don't use any of those. It was decided based on testing different locations for the "sign up" button. More people are able to find it and sign up when it is on the far right. I'm not at all convinced that the increase in sign ups is a result of unintended sign ups (as claimed by Gilles). We aren't interested in those and would change it if that was the case.

Answer (score 31):

> [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) - We are working on making this change. It is a little involved, so give us some time to get it working. The plan is to do this for all of the drop downs.

[moderation](/questions/tagged/moderation)

Our link to the diamond moderator dashboard got shoved out of the way a bit, which is unfortunate: that link's inside a dropdown menu which, first, has to load before the link shows up.

[image]

In countries like Australia ping time can make loading take a few seconds. That's a bit of inconvenience we just didn't have before, so this becomes sort of a functional downgrade.

Either one of these things happening would be good:

- Make the dashboard link **a static part of the page** that doesn't have to load first. When I click the diamond menu, show that "mod messages" grey banner with the dashboard link *straight away.* By all means load the messages to show in there, but don't make me wait on those in order to access the dashboard.
- Move the dashboard link out of the diamond menu so it doesn't have to wait on that load time and so we can click it straight away. We were OK with that before when it was a "mod" link, it might not have been the prettiest thing but only a limited audience was going to see it anyway:

  [image]

Comment: If you middle-click/scroll-click the diamond, it goes to where the mod link used to go.

Comment: @Oded It certainly doesn't for me on Worldbuilding right now, with Firefox 52.4 on Linux. If I manage to click using the scroll wheel without scrolling, it does nothing; if I thumb-click (which with my settings normally opens a link in a new tab), then a new tab opens to the same page I'm already at. Not useful. And of course, that's **so** not discoverable.

Comment: @Oded I can't reproduce that behavior. For me, middle-click/scroll-clicking the diamond opens the community homepage in a new tab.

Comment: Huh. Seems I was wrong there. I was sure it was something that was implemented :(

Comment: I'm in the US with a good network connection and I'm seeing that lag today, too.  (I didn't before the broader rollout.)  Making the dashboard link a static part of the page so we get it before the messages load would be really helpful; 80-90% of the time when I click the diamond it's to get to that link.

Comment: FWIW, we are looking into the bug that the middle-click/scroll-click isn't working.

Comment: @JoeFriend Yey! That would be helpful as well. My preference is either of the bullet points, but I'll settle for that. The first bullet point just seems pretty sensible, especially, but maybe costly to implement.

Comment: @doppelgreener Correct, the first bullet point is a much bigger change. We are looking at it but no promises.

Comment: @JoeFriend Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: @JoeFriend I've noticed the middle-click is working, and I appreciate that it is. Thanks for that improvement. :)

Answer (score 27):

*Disclaimer: I'm not a designer and I don't have any aspirations to be one. I'm also speaking as a user and not as an employee.*

I wonder if there can be a compromise on labels:

> There is no room for legible labels in the current design. The font would have to be so small that it is arguable if it would help many people. (The [example posted to meta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opoIr.png) cheated a bit by changing "achievements" to the much shorter "awards".)

So that we are all talking the same thing, here is the image:

[image]

On the topic, [poke commented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301845/new-top-bar-is-live/301847#comment981585_301847) with a link to [Myth #13: Icons enhance usability](http://uxmyths.com/post/715009009/myth-icons-enhance-usability), which notes:

> The Microsoft Outlook toolbar is a good example: the former icon-only toolbar had poor usability and changing the icons and their positioning didn’t help much. What did help was the [introduction of text labels next to the icons](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jensenh/2005/11/01/the-importance-of-labels/). It immediately fixed the usability issues and people started to use the toolbar. In [another study](https://www.uie.com/brainsparks/2006/02/20/orbitz-cant-get-a-date/), the team of UIE observed that people remember a button’s position instead of the graphic interpretation of the function.

In other words:

1. labels are most important for new user discovery and
2. position is more important than the actual icon for experienced users.

By coincidence, our top bar accumulates more items as the user becomes more experienced. This suggests a compromise solution: **use text labels when a new icon is added to a user's top bar and remove labels for icons a user already knows**. Anonymous users would have the network and help icons labeled in addition to the "Log in" and Sign Up" links:

[image: Label help and network]

There's quite a bit of horizontal room at this stage. We really don't lose much room at the next stage:

[image: My sock on a new site]

My mockup is cramped and I used "awards", but there's a lot of room here to space out icons + labels. A competent designer would do a much better job—maybe good enough to look ok. (Also, I somehow got bigger and brighter lettering here. I'm not going to try to find out why, but I like my first mockup much better.)

By the time someone has access to the review queue, they will have a pretty good idea of where the inbox and achievement icons are. As long as we *substitute* the review icon for help without rearranging the old icons, it probably wouldn't hurt too much to remove some labels:

[image: My sock is on SO. SOrry!]

At this point, the items taking up space are reputation and badges. For a very small subset of users, there's also some moderator icons to be added. Obviously, it would be great to label everything. But the top bar is really crowded for mods:

[image: Don't have diamond moderator sock.]

I don't have a good solution to that, but maybe we can rely on moderators to have learned the position of icons over the years? If we can somehow guarantee they won't move around in the future (and yes, I anticipate the top bar will change again at some point) maybe that will suffice?

**Notes on the [mockup example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300829/new-top-bar-is-coming-to-the-stack-exchange-network/300872#300872)**:

- I'm a fan of small fonts, but it is a usability problem for others. I think bigger labels would be better.
- While "awards" != "achievements", I'm ok with that inconsistency. For that matter, I like awards as a term for the amalgamation of reputation gains, badge awards and new privileges. I'm not sure we are tied to achievements other than using that phrase in [describing the top bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=achievements). It's not defined or used in the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=achievements).
- I'm not sure it even makes sense to label achievements. Most of the time, it doesn't need to be clicked. Only when you have something new does it matter for most people. And when there's something new, it helpfully lights up. Same can be said of the inbox.
- The mockup was also cheated by including review twice for some reason. So there's more space available.

---

Counter-argument: "I don't know, dude. **It looks weird to have some icons labeled and not others.**"

Yes, I agree. But that's why I call it a compromise. For the vast majority of users, it won't matter, however. Very few users get enough reputation to get a review icon. For new users, everything would be labeled to maximize discoverability (and presumably, engagement). Once people are used to the inbox and achievement icons, I don't think they need the labels. (Unless we redesign the top bar in an incompatible way, of course.)

Comment: Nice! Note that the old top bar also had some inconsistency in that some things were text (log in, review, tour, help) and others were unlabeled icons (inbox, achievements). So maybe the counter argument isn't that strong.

Comment: I really appreciate this deep dive into the UI... I'm not *personally* bothered by the inbox and achievements not having labels. I think a big part of the concern I've been hearing is that, since there's no understood symbol for "review" that it may be better to "stop trying to make fetch happen"... I'm interested to see what the poll turns up but without an option for "I abstain in hopes of something else" - admittedly not helpful - I'm not really sure the complaints will stop. Worth pointing out that mods are a varied bunch, we're not all super users.

Comment: @Catija: Yeah. I don't have a good solution for a moderator on a new site who is also fairly new to the network. It's a rough transition.

Comment: For reference the previous label proposals for labels were [canon's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351081) and [Journeyman Geek's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300872), but I don't think anyone had suggested removing labels for experienced users before. On the whole, I think that's an acceptable compromise (even though I think a much better way of saving horizontal space would be to remove the reputation and especially the badges — but to partly compensate I'd like my username where the reputation is).

Comment: Yes, the font size is an issue (I wish my eyesight allowed me to be a fan of small fonts). I think “awards” instead of “achievements” is fine. I also think it would be ok to skip the labels for mod icons, because mods visit the site every day and will quickly adapt to the one or two items, unlike people who visit only when they have a question and can't be expected to have any muscle memory.

Comment: One caveat is that the switch from icons to labels should be based on a **network-wide** criterion and not a per-site criterion. Otherwise the icons will not be in the same location on all sites.

Comment: Given that new mods are already contacted with various helpful links (and must accept the mod agreement before they get the new goodies), I think we have ample opportunities to tell them "hey, about those new things in your top bar" without having to add labels to the top bar itself.  Labeling the new stuff (other than mod stuff) and not everything is a nice teaching tool.

Answer (score 26):

> Concern: Moving the site switcher from the left to the right is
>   confusing. Move it back.
>
> Status: status-bydesign
>
> Explanation: We know that this will take some getting use to, but
>   based on previous experience with changes like this we are confident
>   that everyone can make this adjustment.

I am pretty sure that when the Coca-Cola Bottling company released New Coke they said almost exactly the same thing...

I urge you to reconsider.

Comment: Love that last sentence!!

Comment: Unfortunately, Coca-Cola's revenue is much more directly related to the amount they sell than SE's is related to clicks on the site switcher.

Answer (score 23):

> ### Site switcher
>
> **Concern:** Moving the site switcher from the left to the right is
>   confusing. Move it back.
>
> **Status:** [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)
>
> **Explanation:** We know that this will take some getting use to, but
>   based on previous experience with changes like this we are confident
>   that everyone can make this adjustment.

What's **really** confusing is that in the mobile skin it's still on the left. Since I use both mobile and desktop most days, that's really going to slow down my ability to adjust. Can we have some consistency?

Comment: Seeing as they won't align SO with the rest of the network seems like they're against consistency. But I agree this is needed.

Comment: as a workaround you can use a script to get the switcher back on the left https://stackapps.com/questions/7603/top-navigation-choices

Answer (score 23):

Personally, I think this is NOT a good change. It's a bit sad to know that SE has a full UX community of specialists and SE has not asked for their opinion first.

For starters, this probably won't pass any heuristic usability tests (you can use [the set of Nielsen heuristics](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/), or [Schneiderman's eight rules](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~ben/goldenrules.html) or [Jill Gerhardt-Powal cognitive engineering principles for improving the performance of the human computer](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10447319609526147) as known examples, or Weinschenk and Barker's evaluation checklist).

I'm not saying **the old version would pass them**, because it won't. But at least users had several years to get used to those problems. Making a UI change to keep the same issues makes one wonder why these changes are happening.

As for accessibility ... it's quite surprising to see this, specially considering that **accessibility level AA** will be enforced for most US sites and [there are some trials already](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americans_with_Disabilities_Act_of_1990#Case_law).

I did a quick AUTOMATED test, and it shows these (quite incredible) results:

[image]

and just in case you were wondering, most of the errors are in... the top bar:

[image]

**and this is only for accessibility** . There are other important usability issues as well, which added to the accessibility ones makes this quite problematic.

**In short:** it looks like this is a change for the sake of change; has not improved anything and has made many things worse. I can see in the answers that many users already found many errors and problems, although most of them refer to issues such as icons or positioning and may be considered subjective.

However, **tests and heuristics are objective**, and should have been used throughout the entire process of deploying this quite minor *(yet important)* element.

Particularly troublesome are the items marked as [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) because in other words, it means you won't change it no matter what, so it seems you're decided to persist on error despite objective measures and even laws being against you. A bit stubborn if you ask me....

*PS: I belong to several communities. If you want to maintain consistency ... should not you try using the versions that are much better than SO?*

Answer (score 22):

> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) help icon now omnipresent

Why has the "help" icon on the top bar been eliminated?  Now, the only way to as quickly reach "help" is by hovering over the rightmost icon to read "a list of all 171 SE sites", and know it has any relation to "help". One finds "help" only after clicking on the rightmost icon. Viola, there it is, accessible. Why would any designer assume that users, particularly new users, looking for help, would know to click on that rightmost icon?

Comment: What @sumelic said. Check it out not logged in to the network; for example, in a private browsing / incognito window.

Comment: @sumelic But I am not at all a new user; but I used the help button in the *top bar* so frequently (usually to link a newer-ish user to "help" on an issue they are facing); and upon first gaining review privileges, many users *don't know to click on the rightmost icon*, since there is not immediate indicator of where to find  "help" from which they can select a relevant post for a specific user, as the need arises.

Comment: Why should we expect anyone (new or not new) seeking a help menu, click on a button, which upon hovering over it, yields "A list of all 171 Stack Exchange Sites".   This is really my sole concern with the new top bar; the removal of a direct "help" button, fully identified for all who speak (or read) English.  Everything else just seems to be, more or less, positional changes.  Why get rid of what has been a very useful button ("help") for all users?  (We're talking about re-adding ***four letters*** on the top bar)

Comment: Why would a user from only one (out of "171 Stack Exchange sites" have to, retroactively (post-network-wide deployment) try to detail all the changes, and how to do what users were able to do via the top bar?  Why was this overlooked, prior to its network-wide deployment.  I'd suggest that every site (171 of them) receive a post from SE, with a to link to a yet-to-be-created (and from the powers that be)  demonstration for users across the network as how to make the transition more smooth ***for all of us.***  I think that's only fair, and entirely reasonable to ask.

Comment: @amWhy [This was asked when the new-new nav was first pushed to Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343165/new-top-bar-wheres-the-help-menu-gone), and the general answer was "because it was." In other words, they don't think you need a help icon once you reach a certain rep level.

Comment: I agree. For a partial solution, notice that the is a help link in the footer, too.

Answer (score 21):

> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) help icon now omnipresent

Something that I've noticed is it seems like the help area is buried. I recently needed to grab the merge accounts link to give to a user and I really had to hunt around for it. It seems to me that help should be something easy to find. This is especially true since people never seem to look there when they have problems. Hiding the help link will surely only diminish its usage by people who really need it.

Comment: The help link is quite prominent for lower rep users. It's at the top level of the new top bar. Once a user has review privileges, then it it moves to a link within the site switcher.

Comment: @JoeFriend Do users get notified of this change? If I was new and using help quite often then it all of a sudden moved I'd be very confused. It'd make sense for them to get a notification telling them where it is now. That being said there appears to be room for it still so why remove it in the first place?

Comment: @JoeFriend I see that small icon now that you mentioned it. While I agree that is better than burying it, I still don't think it stands out. That little question mark icon blends in with all the other little icons in the little header. I think it is very hard to find once you have 500 rep on a site, and inconspicuous when you have less than 500 rep.

Comment: Imagine if your F1 button on the keyboard suddenly moved to the back side. That doesn't make any sense, no matter how proficient you've been with it. That's like saying "now that you've learned where everything is, we're gonna change it" (what?!)

Comment: @JoeFriend When was the last time you visited the "help" link on a new website you just wanted to check out? I suspect that at least some high-rep users (like Erik here) click the "help" link more often than new users, just to suggest the new users visit it.

Answer (score 19):

This could probably be a comment rather than an answer, but it surprises me that the inconsistency is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). The [How Stack Overflow redesigned the top navigation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/02/14/why-stack-overflow-redesigned-the-top-navigation/) article states things like this:

> We hypothesized that a lack of engagement with the nav was due to a combination of browsing habits, visual hierarchy, and the right-hand position of the layout. Based on research about [F-shaped reading patterns](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/f-shaped-pattern-reading-web-content/) and how readers’ eyes commonly move down the page, it made sense that our navigation was sub-optimal for most people.

And:

> We also hypothesized that the focal point of the page (the logo) caused many users to skip over the small top bar. Plus the nav and top bar quickly scroll out of view when moving down the page.

But also some feedback like:

> “Nav looks like tags — they might filter, but they don’t look like navigation. Makes you question what it is so I don’t click it and instead go back to Google that I’m familiar with.”
>
> “Cleaner, more organized. Instead of jumbled stuff at top you have to read and decipher you can go to this.”
>
> “More standardized position that you’re used to on other sites.”
>
> “Looks really, really good. By far I like the new one — in the current one, you don’t notice the navigation at all, only the top bar. The (sub) tabs catch my eye before the current navigation.”
>
> “In the old, it is weird to me that the two bars exist separately. This one feels more natural.”
>
> “The new one is cleaner. Less wasted space. Things are more compact on the new one and account info is better grouped. Tabs across the top is preferable because a lot of sites have a similar flow. …much prefer the new one.”

The thing I'm trying to address is that one of the flaws of the old design, according to the article, was [the shattered navigation](https://zgab33vy595fw5zq-zippykid.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/ea5NY.png), the questions/answers being on the right side, ... .

I'm concerned that this issue isn't being addressed with the new-new design, so I'm wondering how you think the new-new design tackles this issue.

Comment: The difference is that traffic to stackoverflow.com/jobs is closely related to the company's revenue, which isn't the case for other sites.

Comment: @Desire I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to say. Are you saying it's not worth to address all the issues mentioned in the article because there's no revenue? I can live with that, but then I wonder what the idea is behind the new-new design? Pretty much none of the points addressed in the original article are solved by the new-new design, but then I why did they reference to that article in [their initial post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300829/new-top-bar-is-coming-to-the-stack-exchange-network) if it isn't relevant anyways.

Answer (score 18):

To be honest, there are a few things with this new design that seem off to me. Most of them have been stated already, from the initial announcement on Stack Overflow to the announcement it was being released network-wide, so I won't restate them here.

However, consistency is a big problem. The main concern with this seems to be it would be too much work to get all the sites inline with SO. I don't understand the reasoning behind this, why can't you just get SO inline with the rest of the sites?

However, one small thing that seems to nag at me is the reputation number seems to stand out too much. I think it would make sense to unbold it at least and even have it be the same colour as the icons.

The reasoning behind not adding labels to the icons also seems odd. You yourself state "Icons are hard" then won't implement a simple change for them to make them clearer. *Awards* is shorter and conveys the same meaning as achievements so I don't see why it's "cheating" at all. It makes sense.

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) A possible bug with the icons is when you middle click them they just open up the same page you're on in a new tab. I would expect either nothing or to open a default page associated with the icon e.g. /help. This behaviour seems to be implemented for review.

<s>I've just noticed that the StackExchange logo on the bar has also been updated, will this be changed on https://stackexchange.com/ too? Also, it is a darker colour on the main meta than other sites, not sure if this is intentional but it is confusing. Looking further it appears the SFF has the lighter colour and other sites like PPCG and Gaming have the main meta colour, is there any reasoning for this inconsistency? All meta's appear to use the orange colour though, though I'm not sure why this is...</s> This appears to have been changed back again now, why though? Who knows. (Side note: it's hard to compile a list of bugs and feature-requests if you keep updating it...)

Another thing I've noticed since the new update is that I open multiple tabs before opening my inbox and rep dropdowns. On the old bar when I opened one on one tab the others would refresh and the counts would go away. Now I have to refresh the page myself for these to update. It is a bit annoying.

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) The rep popup on the achievements icon is not centred, I would expect it to be so.

[image: Icon image]

Comment: I created a post about the reputation numbers not being clear when the new top bar was initially introduced. Apparently the problem hasn't been addressed yet: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301042/reputation-and-badge-counts-are-harder-to-read-on-the-new-top-bar

Comment: @TotZam To be honest I'm losing hope on things like that ever being addressed. I do quite like the coloured numbers instead of the white for the badges and they are still readable.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder We are looking at the rep number being bold concern. It is ultimately a design choice and thus subjective. The SE logo was a bug and is fixed. Regarding the counts across multiple tabs, this works for me (when cleared on one it gets updated on all). And, the indicator is intentionally offset. When a single digit this allows you to see most of the icon. Again, this one is subjective.

Comment: @JoeFriend Do you have any further comments regarding consistency and middle clicking the icons? Also if you know something is subjective and is causing questions what's the harm in making it configurable? A user has managed to make a good userscript to do so you could always incorporate that.

Answer (score 18):

I'm not sure what it is, but the new top bar just *feels* cramped.

The font is kind of thick, and that makes it look smaller. You're shoving more icons on there, half of which are more confusing than just a plain text label, so that's also more cramped.

The proportions just feel way wrong. The old bar felt a lot cleaner.

### End review: =(

FWIW, I also am way less likely to go to review now, because it's smudged off right, and I have to think about which icon it is, and *ugh*.

---

The fact that the Area51 and stackexchange.com top bars are not changed is going to make this even harder to get used to.

Comment: Both of your edits are mentioned in the question...

Comment: Regarding review: we've just identified a bug that would've prevented the indicator from appearing for you on any site where you can review. Should be fixed within the next day - I expect this might make a significant difference, as review *should* be unobtrusive when there's not much to do.

Answer (score 14):

Regarding the site switcher, you said

> We know that this will take some getting use to, but based previous experience with changes like this we are confident that everyone can make this adjustment.

Are you planning on moving the site switcher to the right-hand side for all SE sites so that we can "get used to it" across the entire network instead of having to remember whether we're on SO or not?

Comment: From the linked post's edit history, "*Assuming no significant issues are discovered we will roll out to all sites within the next couple weeks*"... not sure if the fact it was removed means something but it's generally seemed like the intention was for all sites to have the same top bar (excepting SO). Moderators have it on their sites in addition, so *technically* all sites have it... just to only specific users.

Comment: @bjmyers Yes, all users/sites will have the experience that currently exists here on meta-se. That goes live tomorrow morning.

Comment: Ah, I didn't read closely enough.  I was distracted by the heading saying that SO and SE network sites would not be consistent and missed the whole rollout announcement. :)

Answer (score 14):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) To see all inbox items one has to scroll all the way down through recent items. To be consistent with the achievements and reviews tabs, I suggest to put the link at the top:

[image]

Comment: Actually those links refer to all items available to the community. Meanwhile the "see all inbox items" is a link to Stack Exchange instead of your current site. Honestly "INBOX" and "ACHIEVEMENTS" should be linked to your entire history. And possibly "REVIEW QUEUES" too.

Answer (score 13):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Can we have a link to the meta review queues (either individually or as a link to the whole page) with the rest of the review icons?

### Rationale

- In the old design, I could get to meta review with two clicks (review>meta review queues). Now it will be further away (site switcher>meta>review or review>all queues>meta review queues) and I will be much less likely to bother checking the queues
- I can glance at all the other review queues to see whether they need attention, but can't tell anything about meta
- Users new to review may not even know of the existence of meta review queues, since they have been neatly hidden away.

Comment: What if one of the review queues in the dropdown list was collectively "Meta reviews", showing whether there is anything to review at meta? That link could then lead to the meta review queues page with more details.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Sounds like a good idea

Comment: @JoeFriend will this light up with grey/red dots?

Comment: @boboquack No, but you have easy access now. :)

Answer (score 13):

It used to be like this:

[image]

Now it's like this:

[image]

What's with the tiny unbalanced podium for the number?

(I'm using the [top bar customizer](https://stackapps.com/questions/7603/top-navigation-choices), but even without it, the tiny podium is still there and it's just as crooked, except it's on the right)

---

Update: This isn't such a problem on SO apparently, and it even raises the bubble up to reveal most of the cup on hover:

[image]

So this is only a problem outside of SO.

Comment: The change is posted off to the side, just like for when you received messages. Here's a view with two active notifications: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omphW.png)

Comment: ok so the inbox icon is mostly visible, but with so many symbols, the cup is mostly obscured and you can't tell what's behind the green bubble

Comment: The argument against using text labels along with the icons is that the text would be too small. So if we care about font sizes, how about getting rid of the "podium" and using that extra space (both height and width) to show the gained rep in a larger font?

Answer (score 13):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) This feature has disappeared:

[Don't require a click to switch between sites, inbox, and Achievements on the new topbar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210177)

(You can still try it out at [the main site](https://stackexchange.com/) and [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).)

Comment: While I'd like to see the old behavior back, I'm pretty sure this was done on purpose.

Comment: I actually didn't care for the old behavior. As long as dropping down the list *clears* all notifications, if you accidentally bump the mouse, you lose all prayer of seeing what's new. Happens to me all the time with the inbox as it is.

Comment: @barto This is [tag:status-declined] since we changed it explicitly due to feedback during new top bar testing on SO. The [feedback was strong](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343136/7782017) that it was too easy to invoke an alternate menu.

Answer (score 13):

You've made getting to the meta of a site when you're on the main site much more tedius now.  I used to be able to click the top left thing (don't remember exactly what it looked like, it was pretty much automatic by the time you made the change), and easily get to meta.

After this change, I naturally did the same thing, and got some mess I had no interest in.  I did some digging around and clicking, but never was able to get to meta.  I finally got to meta by clicking on my user icon at top right of center, clicking *meta user* (or something like that), then eventually getting to where I could click *questions* to see the questions on meta.

Yucc!

**STOP WITH THE GRATUITIOUS CHANGES!**

Comment: @sumelic: I see that works.  I didn't even notice that icon.  It got lost in the clutter.  But the more important point is THAT'S NOT HOW IT USED TO WORK.  There was no good reason to break everyone's flow and waste their time while they learn the new arbitrary little details.  I come here for various reasons, but having to learn a new UI isn't one of them.

Answer (score 12):

> [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) - We will be fixing a variety of issues that are related to the new review indicator on smaller sites (aka not Stack Overflow).

There's no red dot on the review icon on any site that I have a decent rep-count in, for example the Workplace, IPS, and Worldbuilding stacks.

All of them look like this:

[image]

We have to click on the button to see if there's anything in the review queues.

But at least I don't see a count for review queues that I can't see any more, so at least that's a thing.

Comment: This seems to be roundabout suggesting there should be a grey dot (or some kind of dot) when there's any reviews at all, even when there's not enough for the red dot. If that's what you're after then I agree with that, though I think this answer should more explicitly request a grey dot or something. :)

Comment: I had no idea there was a different between a grey dot on this icon and a red dot.  I'd just like to see **any** kind of indication that there's things in the review queues to look at.  Right now, there's nothing until you click that icon (at least to my eyes).

Comment: Right now there's a grey dot for a small number of reviews and a red dot for lots of reviews.

Comment: @doppelgreener To clarify, though, you mean per-queue (after you already clicked the icon).

Comment: No.  I mean an indication on the icon on the top bar, as shown in my screen-cap above.  I know that when I click on the icon, I see notifications per queue.  Basically, I want to see if theres any thing in the queues before I click the icon.  Just the same as I see notifications on reps and the inbox.

Comment: @ChristianRau Yeah, there are dot indicators for the queues themselves -- not for the icon. The icon lights up orange if there's lots of reviews to do, but does nothing if there's only some.

Comment: @doppelgreener Bingo, I've made myself understood!

Comment: If you click the button, you will see which review queues that have been awared a silver badge! On SO it is a red dot, on all other sites it is a silver badge. Silver badge is a good thing, yeah? Lets leave it be.

Comment: I don't want to click the button to see if there's items to review.  For the inbox and the cheevo button, there's badges to indicate there's stuff there to look at.  I just want the same for the review queue icon. This worked ok in the previous version (even though the number was largely nonsensical).

Comment: FWIW, this is currently broken for you on several (though not all) of the sites where you're active: it'll *never* light up unless you have mod tool access. Should be fixed in the next day; sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks for the feedback, appreciate it.

Comment: Fixed now - see if you have an easier time over the next few days.

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks, but this doesn't appear to be fixed for me.  On my three most active sites, the top bar looks as above (no badge on the 'review queue' icon).  When I click on the icon, there are queues to be reviewed.

Comment: Heh... Yeah, there's not much in the queues there ATM. I'll check back in a week and adjust thresholds if that holds.

Comment: @Shog9 Ok, I get it now.  So the other notifications are user-based, but the queues are a global thing, so suck up global resources.  Lowering the thresholds would impact global resources more.

Answer (score 12):

> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [See this post for details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304445/experiment-review-needed-indicator-logic-for-sites-that-sometimes-have-empty-qu)

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

I am here to propose a feature request about the review icon in the top bar.  feature-request. The proposal made in the [Review queue false positives](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300829/new-top-bar-is-coming-to-the-stack-exchange-network/300864#300864) is not to light up the review icon when there are no actionable tasks. But currently, it is happening the other way round. The users have to check every time if there are pending posts. This is not user-friendly.

Borrowing image from the post: [New top bar is coming to the Stack Exchange network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300829/357396)

[image: Screen shot of the Top bar for a high rep member]

In the above image, the review icon is it up with a red color(or a variation) indicating pending items for review.

I am not sure whether this feature is not working or temporarily removed for time being The review bar becoming totally red is next to impossible on smaller sites with less traffic (particularly beta sites).

Currently, there is no indication of pending posts. We only know if we click on the icon and check the pending items manually.

[image: Review icon picture from a beta site]

The above image is a screenshot from [Hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/). We can see that there were two pending items eligible for review but there's no such indication on the top bar. There used to be a number beside review option in the old design to indicate pending posts.

I am asking for an indication (Probably a glow or similar thing based on the number of pending posts like we get when we receive a badge) on the review icon even if there are **3 or 4 actionable posts**.

Comment: That's a bug. Problem is, it's working fine on Stack Overflow, so they have little motivation to fix it. They will, but it might take several months. (The rest of the network is not nearly as important as SO)

Comment: "The rest of the network is not nearly as important as SO". I am not happy with it. Other sites are also a part of SE network.They should consider beta and graduated sites with less traffic too.

Comment: They do, and most bugs reported here affect the whole network, including SO, but now with this hybrid top bar it is different. I hope to be wrong and see the review icon fixed shortly, just giving a personal view and advising not to build our hopes too high. Best example I can give is a bug in the android app where your vote disappears after you cast it. The bug exists for two years. The team knows about the bug but will never fix it because they officially don't care about the app anymore.

Comment: @ICanHazUpvotzPleez SO got this months ago. now only other sites, including MSE got it. SO having high priority

Answer (score 9):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

There used to be a minor animation for the notifications. They're now gone:

[image]

However, it still works in the [SO](//stackoverflow.com) top bar:

[image]

Comment: The SO top bar is also taller. I'm guessing there's not really enough room for the animations on the regular one?

Comment: Actually this animation was [irritating](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301414/number-stand-still-aka-dont-move-the-top-bar-numbers-while-hovering-over-the). I'm really glad they removed it.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I liked that animation.

Answer (score 7):

As expected - there's a few comments on various chats about... folk knowing what they are. None on Super User, but I've posted a quick guide on it on [Meta.SU](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/12692/new-top-bar-coming-soon-what-does-it-mean-for-me).

I know the blog isn't used *much* for this (and I suppose a meta post would do), but an equivalent, official post showing the features of the new nav turning up on *all* the site side bars would probably help the transition a fair bit. Might also be a good chance to write about the process of working out what the 2017 top bar revision  needed to be too.

Comment: Thanks for the guide! I've linked to it on Math.SE.

Comment: @journeymangeek Nice job.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the review icon is not that great. I prefer "review", but I'm now used to clicking on the strange edit symbol in a word balloon (#6 on the survey). I have a screenshot of the choices for the review icon below.

Please under no circumstances use the flag (#5). Flags mean one thing on the Internet - this thing is bad and clicking this button will do something to it.

Stack Exchange already has a flag icon in use for, guess what, flagging a comment.

[image: Flag comment button]

I do not see anything good coming out of having a flag in the top bar. It just sounds like a bad idea. (Yes, I get the whole thing about flags ending up in the review, but no.)

---

I don't like anything with a clipboard (#1 and #4). Reason being that clipboards are associated with pasting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.
Maybe this is finally where I can find the Stack Exchange notes section, or where I can store often-used comments...

That leaves just #2, #3 and the current icon. 
**Of the icons there #2 is by far the best.** 
It's some kind of list in a word balloon. Whatever, I'll middle-click on it and move on. At least this one makes sense for a review icon.

I don't care for the YouTube verified paragraph icon (#3). What does a review icon need a check mark for?

[image: Review icons]

So please just go with #2.

Comment: It's the first time I encounter the concept of “youtube verified paragraph icon”, but the idea of “verified paragraph” is a pretty good one for review. Reviewing is about verifying if the (proposed) contents of post meets certain criteria. #2, on the other hand, looks like a speech balloon. What on earth does this have to do with review?

Comment: @Gilles #3 does appear to be the best but it doesn't seem to match the theme of the other icons.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder #3 is also the one I find the least bad. I might not spontaneously guess “review”, but once I know what it's about, I find it a good match (unlike the inbox icon, which does not look at all like the physical object to me).

Comment: I agree (with David) that #2 is the least bad, with #3 as runner-up.  But it’s not “some kind of list” in a word balloon; it’s an emblem of [the review queue page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRNMi.png). I believe that it would be the least hard to “get used to”. But I also agree with the large number of people who ask: why should we have to get used to something new at all? Why change?  I have yet to see a coherent explanation of any benefits to this change; AFAICT it’s change for the sake of change.

Comment: I actually thought #4 was the best. It's a clipboard (makes you think of a boss going around and doing "performance reviews") with a checkmark (makes you think of verification - "checking off" on a valid post). Plus it matches the slightly more solid, blocky look of the other icons.

Comment: Considered in isolation, #2 is the least bad of the bunch, but it's got one major problem: it too obviously means "chat".

Comment: All of them are bad. "Pen writing wordlines in a speech bubble" is not indicative of a "review" task, at all. Yet if we look at the options, ***FOUR*** of the icons are in this category: 1, 2, 3, and 6.  Only #6 (the current icon) has a pen, but I dare you to tell me that the other three aren't just variations on that theme. #3 gets the farthest from it, being "check the wordlines" which is...maybe...review-y ("check the thing"). #2 is a bulleted list and #1 uses a clipboard instead of a speech bubble.

Comment: IMO #2 still has the same major problem as the current one, which is that it's clearly a chat bubble, so I, for one, would very strongly expect it to be the inbox, i.e. people talking to me.

Comment: #2 looks like chat or a bulleted list (remember to look at it *at scale*, not just the giant version).  #3 evokes text and "checking", which is what reviewers do, so it's the best of these options.

Answer (score 7):

It's not at all obvious which icons/buttons in the top bar will drop down on click vs. taking me to a new page.

They all change in the same way on hover (lighten the background), and aren't grouped by drop-down vs. not-drop-down so I would expect them all to do the same thing (there are no drop down arrows).

I would make all buttons drop down or differentiate them more clearly.

Comment: I think the only one that doesn't drop down is the user profile, right?

Comment: @catija and the stack exchange logo now, which used to drop down.

Comment: Based on the top answer here and the comments on Monica's answer, that functionality may be going away.

Answer (score 6):

I have things to say about these:

[image]

⚑ Flag is obviously already used for flagged messages. It wouldn't make sense to use it for non-flagged items. My first thought if I saw that would be "Somehow I gained moderator privileges?"

✓ Check mark is obviously already used for accepted answer on the site. These are the top two symbols I have problems with you trying to use them for review queue. These just don't make any sense.

☰ Hamburger icon with a smaller bottom bun? It's for settings, everybody knows that thanks to modern GUI practices. Only in the second icon it resembles a bullet list. Hamburger with a check mark for "confirm settings"? List of questions with an accepted answer? Don't think so.

Dashboard icon in the left column conveys a meaning of a task productivity tool, like Trello. Dashboard with a check mark… something about accepted answers?

Comment icon means… "comment". Do you gotta leave comments in the review queue? Sure, sometimes, but not always. There's gotta be a better icon though.

Bottom right is a comment about a stapler.

---

Look how obvious the inbox icon is − there's no confusion. "Incoming messages" is exactly what it means. And the question mark icon for help. Such a great choice. And the cup with a star for awards!

Surely you can find better options for a review queue, something that says "review" with its symbol and doesn't cross over with already used symbols on the site.

The presented options are not quite as good at representing what they mean as the other icons. Please think of better options to choose from.

---

Why not just the word "review"?

Comment: "*It's for settings, everybody knows that thanks to modern GUI practices*" is not true. I thought it was for menus in general. For settings I would expect to see either a cog or a spanner.

Comment: That's why I said thanks to modern GUI practices, it's being used for both menus and settings interchangeably these days. In any case, neither conveys the meaning of "review" or "queue".

Comment: "Bottom right is a comment about a stapler."  Haha!  While I had not seen 'stapler' in that icon, now that's going to be the only thing I *can* see.  Which of course is quite terrible for the review icon.

Comment: *"My first thought if I saw that would be 'Somehow I gained moderator privileges?'"* Yes, exactly! You have! These sites are moderated by the community, and anyone with privileges to review posts *does* have moderator privileges. Most of what you're reviewing in the review queue *are* flagged posts. Some of them are flagged by the system, some of them are flagged by humans, but they're still being flagged and need your attention. Great icon, instantly recognizable.

Comment: @CodyGray what I meant is "moderator privileges for reviewing flagged posts" which as the majority of users know, means something is very wrong with the post to the point where users are not capable of dealing with it. **Flag = users can't fix this, call the police.** Not the icon you want for to use something that concerns normal users. You've got 50k of rep man, you should know that's not right.

Comment: I very much disagree with that. There is only one type of flag that is reviewed exclusively by moderators, and that's the "requires moderator attention" flag (also commonly known as the "other" flag). The standard flag types are all reviewed by the community, using the review queues, so a flag seems like a completely appropriate mnemonic device for that.

Comment: @CodyGray how did you learn that information? When I hover over the "flag" text, the tooltip says "flag this post for serious problems or moderator attention". To me "serious problems" means it's not something trivial that users can resolve without the help of higher ups. Otherwise there are close votes and editing, which *is* for most users. Perhaps the difference between how I and you view flags is a result of miscommunication on the site's part.

Comment: Serious problems doesn't mean they cannot be resolved by regular users. Trusted users have moderation privileges. That is a fundamental aspect of Stack Exchange's design. For example, "not an answer" and "very low quality" flags put a post into the "Low Quality Posts" review queue, where users with review privileges review them, deciding whether they look OK, need editing, or should be deleted. How did I learn this? I've been around here for, like, ever. 7+ years now. Maybe the UI could be clearer, but I don't think it's miscommunicating. It does say " *or* moderator attention".

Comment: @CodyGray it's weird to me that you can achieve the same effects via both close votes and flags, after you've earned enough rep. One has the connotation you describe, but the other less so. Again, this feels like a problem in the site's communication language to me.

Comment: At low rep levels, all you can do is flag for closure. At higher rep levels, all you can do is vote to close. Flags to close are automatically converted into votes to close. The idea is not to break your original routine just because you passed a magic threshold. If you were flagging successfully before, we want you to keep up the good work at dispatching garbage. Yes, both close flags (from low-rep users) and close votes (from higher-rep users) put a post into the Close review queue. I see them all as flags, certainly in a metaphorical sense.

Comment: Well, that's what I find wrong with this approach − if you pass a threshold, why should the name of the thing change then? Just keep calling it flags, no? Why suddenly rename it to "close vote" and divide between two differently connotated categories of review actions? I find it confusing. Flag icon to me only bears the extremely serious connotation, and I find using it for both trivial and not so serious issues wrong.

Comment: @user1306322: The name of the thing changes because the effect of a flag is not identical to the effect of a vote. One *only* calls for attention; the other also takes a definite step toward resolution. Mashing them together as the same concept would just be confusing.

Comment: @NathanTuggy ye that's kinda my point.

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to add to the frustration about the site switcher being moved and the StackExchange icon becoming a simple link to a completely different site from the current stack.

Given that the search bar right next to that icon has the current stack name in it, the icon and top bar become part of the current site interface, so having that icon jump to another site is not intuitive.

Additionally moving the site switcher away to the other side adds to the confusion - especially given the iconography doesn't exactly scream "click here to go to another stack" as opposed to "hay maybe this goes to the chat" (not that I'd want it to).

---

The changes does of course lead to an unexpected but effective use case...

[image: Site Switcher Animation]

(Animated GIF - click to view - I figured it's less annoying to show a static image in the post)

Answer (score 5):

Well, I noticed this today:

[image]

That looks familiar.

Not sure what this means...I think Google made this change after the SO top bar redesign. Did they, um, "borrow" the icon from you?*

[image] [image]

---

*Yes, I see the different corner radius and spacing between the top and bottom halves [of the stapler](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301845/new-top-bar-is-live#comment982115_301972). They're clearly the same design.

Comment: It seems that SE kind of "borrowed" the icon from Google. [It's existed in the Material Design Icons set](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/a6145e167b4a3a65640dd6279319cbc77a7e4e96/maps/drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_rate_review_black_48dp.png) since May 12th 2015. It's called ["rate review"](https://material.io/icons/#ic_rate_review)  in the set. But then they are licensed with the Apache 2.0 license, so SE can use them if they took 'em from over there. Maybe they changed the Google Docs logo to attract SE users? Heck, I should become a detective...

Comment: Good research, @Zizouz212. I wondered if it was an openly-available icon, but failed to track it down.

Comment: In retrospect, this probably should have been a question rather than a response to the announcement.

Answer (score 4):

### Site-specific feature requests

I can see you're already getting inundated here with feedback and requests for changes on the new top bar, and that's just for network-wide things. Some sites which have especially customised styles ([Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com) and [Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com)) must be giving you particular headaches since there are assorted **site-specific** bugs and feature-requests relating to the top bar. To make things simpler than having to follow all the per-site metas, I'm going to try to collect these site-specific issues here.

**Science Fiction & Fantasy**

1. [Can we make our new top bar slightly transparent black, like our old one?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11425/31394)
2. [Can we get our blag link back, please?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11421/31394)
3. [Can we make our Top Bar sticky?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11422/31394) (not sure how site-specific this one really is)

**Ask Ubuntu**

1. [Bug with new top bar](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/17342) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
2. [Review queue false negatives on the new top bar](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/17346) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)
3. [New navbar bug review queues not operating as expected](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/17349)

**Other sites?**

I've looked on a dozen or so meta sites, but didn't see any others with topbar-related bugs or feature requests. If anyone knows of some, please edit them into this answer.

Comment: If they're anything like some of the guys on Workplace, they haven't been able to find the link to Meta yet (or are just protesting the change by purposely not finding it...)

Comment: We have fixed a few site-specific bugs and are happy to look at new ones as their identified. The sticky top bar request and the review queues issues aren't site-specific and are [tag:status-review]. The color and blog link request are [tag:status-declined] since we are trying to avoid too many site-specific overrides.

Comment: @JoeFriend Thanks for the response! Could you or someone else on your team possibly add the [tag:status-declined] tag and a quick explanation to the colour and blog questions? (As a mod on that site, I could add the tag, but for reasoning I'd just have to link to your comment here.)

Comment: @JoeFriend - thanks for the response. Would a feature request to change the color of the bar network wide be better, instead of just for SFF?

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

What's with the super bright search input on black (all sites except SO)?

[image]
[image]

vs

[image]
[image]

What gives? <sub><s>whose bright idea was this?</s></sub>

---

Update: ok I was talking from the point of view of a user who knows where the search is and how to use it, which is apparently not very common, so I understand this design decision and can't really vote against that.

---

*More important update:*

As we've discussed in the comments, it seems like contrast helps with visibility and increases search usage, which is good for reducing duplicates and helping people find answers sooner.

But **I'd like to ask the design team:** why did you choose to not make the search bar as extremely noticeable on StackOverflow as on all the other SE sites? StackOverflow has most questions asked per day, and by far the most review activity than on any other SE site. How do you explain this decision?

Comment: Contrast. It's something that they learned after redesigning the top bar for SO. The original iteration of SO's top bar was stark white. There was no way to find the search box unless you had eagle-eyed vision and could discern the tiny grey border. The final version of the SO top bar is a light gray, but I could still stand to see more contrast there. The white-on-black is excellent design: it makes the search box stand out, which is exactly what we want to drive users towards.

Comment: @CodyGray Ok, I get that. Then why, against this reasoning, is it so invisible on StackOverflow, where it would help the most?

Comment: @CodyGray It's strange, I do not have eagle eyesight, but I perfectly distinguish the white input field on a gray background.

Comment: @Alex78191 Not that strange. It is obviously distinguishable *now*. As I said, the final version made the top bar background a light gray. The original version was white, as was the search field, so the only separation was a thin, light-gray border. *That* wasn't especially distinguishable, especially on imperfectly-calibrated monitors. The current design is much better than the original, but I still think it could use more contrast. As for *"why, against this reasoning, is it so invisible on StackOverflow, where it would help the most?"*, I have no idea. You'd have to ask the design team.

Comment: @CodyGray You should create two comments to answer two different people.

Comment: @Alex78191 Why? The other person is the one who posted this answer, so they get notified anyway. Fewer comments are better.

Comment: @CodyGray I thought that the other

Comment: @Alex78191 don't worry I got the notification and I would like to forward my question to the design team but idk how. I'll update my answer to include that so it's more visible. Hope they're reading them.

Comment: Oops. Jumped the gun on this one. It should be completed by tomorrow 12/22.

Comment: @JoeFriend I preferred the old look; there should be an option to change it back.

Comment: I rather like it. Can't please everyone I guess?

Comment: @JoeFriend so you make major design changes that affect millions of people based on +8/-3 request? I think that is a mistake.

Comment: @ShadowWizard we don't know that it was only because of voting here; I mean, much more popular things get declined all the time.  The new top bar has been live for a couple months now, so they might have other data.  (Besides, it's not like the previous state had *any* voting behind it; we had unobtrusive search, then in-your-face search, and now we have super-unobtrusive search.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio true. Still irritating though.

Answer (score 3):

I'm ambivalent about what the site logo should do, and where you put the site switcher. I'll get used to it either way. But the new design is deliberately inconsistent:

1. In the new design, the upper-left stackexchange logo does different things on different sites - on SE it opens the site switcher and on other sites it jumps to SE.
2. The site switcher is in different places on different sites, left on SE and right on everything else.

Whatever you decide on for the new design, it would be least-surprising if the same elements did the same thing on all sites

Comment: this is an artifact of SE.com, chat and Area 51 not yet being updated with the new top bar. They will be soon.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, but it was a bit confusing

Answer (score 1):

[status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

On my MBP, I usually <kbd>Command</kbd>-click a link as the equivalent of middle-clicking (opening in a new tab), since <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-clicking is like right-clicking (open context menu). However, with the new review and site-switcher icons, <kbd>Command</kbd>-click behaves like a normal click (opens the corresponding drop-downs). On an Ubuntu VM running on the same MBP, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-clicking opens the dropdowns.

What happened to break <kbd>Command</kbd>-click open-in-new-tab for these two? This aggravates the slowness of these dropdowns.

Comment: @Joe a month later, is there any progress? (Asking only due to the status planned tag)

Answer (score 1):

## The gap between "Log In" and "Sign Up" at the [Stack Exchange homepage](https://stackexchange.com) is too narrow.

> [image: BUG : MISSING SPACE BETWEEN "LOG IN" LINK AND "SIGN UP" BUTTON ON TOP BAR AT { STACKEXCHANGE.COM } WHEN NOT LOGGED IN!]
> BUGGED LAYOUT : Visit [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com) in your browser's private mode to reproduce this.

**BUG : Missing space between "Log In" link and "Sign Up" button on top bar at [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com) when not logged in!**

On the contrary, the top bar at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) has proper spacing between the "Log In" link and the "Sign Up" button when not logged in!

> [image: ON THE CONTRARY, THE TOP BAR AT { STACKOVERFLOW.COM } HAS THE PROPER SPACING BETWEEN THE "LOG IN" LINK AND THE "SIGN UP" BUTTON WHEN NOT LOGGED IN!]
> CORRECT LAYOUT : Visit [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) in your browser's private mode to reproduce this.

Answer (score -3):

I like new top menu styles.
[image]

but I have the new change to better height & colors in stylish:

```
.top-bar .searchbar input[type="text"].f-input {
    background-color: #363c42;
    color: #e5e6e7;
}

.top-bar._search-open .searchbar input[type="text"].f-input {
    background-color: #363c42;
}

.top-bar .searchbar input[type="text"].f-input:hover {
    box-shadow: none;
}

.top-bar .searchbar input[type="text"].f-input:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
}

.top-bar {
    height: 52px;
}

.top-bar~.container {
    margin-top: 52px;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I find that the tool tip for the hamburger symbol is wrong. Please see screen shot below:

[image]

Comment: What would be a better wording for that tooltip then?

Comment: @rene - The hamburger ICON does not give a full list of all Stack Exchange sites. Instead it gives a list of sites that I am a member of and which ones I have visited. So some wording that reflects the actual functionality would be more appropriate than what is shown above.

Comment: What is wrong with that? If you scroll down the menu you'll see list of all the sites. (under "MORE STACK EXCHANGE COMMUNITIES")

Comment: @rene - A better text may simply be "Other Stack Exchange Sites".