# Top bar not updated for SE.com

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, top-bar, stackexchange.com

The new top bar is not present in https://stackexchange.com/ it still uses the old one.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's now live on https://stackexchange.com!

[image]

Answer (score 9):

This is not a bug yet. First paragraph on the [announcement post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301845/new-top-bar-is-live) says (emphasis is mine):

> We released the new top bar for all users across all communities. The only exceptions are **stackexchange.com**, Area 51, and chat. **They will be coming a little later**.

Comment: must have read over that...