# Join community button on the wrong side of the site switcher

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, design, top-bar

The bright blue "Join this community" button appears on the far right of the new top bar and pushes the site switcher away.

[image]

For consistency it should really appear in the same location as the favicon+badges button in communities you are already part of.

Comment: AKA: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301925/270345

Answer (score 3):

An [answer requesting this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301925/284336) is [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) on the "New top bar is live" announcement post, with the explanation from Joe Friend, lead of the DAG team:

> The primary CTA in this situation is "Join". We previously tested it in various locations and far right was the best. So we will keep the current order.

Answer (score 0):

It seems out of place to *us*, people who have accounts and know what those other icons are.  To someone unfamiliar with the network, those icons probably won't get much action anyway.  That leaves people familiar with the network but who aren't members of *that particular site*, which I suspect is a very small portion of the visits to most sites.

As noted in [another answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304240/162102), SE tested this with the target audience and found this to be the best position.  That's not going to change.  I'm only adding this answer to add another reason for the placement not being as bad *for that audience* as it is for us.  I upvoted the question when I first saw it, but I now realize that that button isn't aimed at me anyway.

Comment: Why can't they show it in the right spot to people who are logged in to SE but aren't members of that particular site, and use the current configuration for people who aren't logged in to SE? After all, the system can tell between the two because the dropdowns still work.