# Is this request for statistics of skipping in reviews hard to accomplish or does it somehow lack visibility?

Tags: support, specific-question, statistics

Related:

- [New top bar is live](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301845/165773) 
  (section "Review queue icon sucks")
- [Review queue updates & icon poll](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357621/839601)

  - [Please change the review icon back to a text link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/350836/839601)
- [Review icon survey](https://www.surveylegend.com/s/eia) by Stack Exchange DAG team

---

I wonder about this stats request: [Looking for stats on how frequency of skip actions correlates with amount of reviews done by user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351269/839601).

It looks like totally ignored by Stack Exchange team for over three months. What could be reason for that? How could it improve to have better chances to be addressed or at least noticed?

---

For a while I thought the reason is that SE team can't afford to spend any effort on involved matters of reviewers attrition. However what I currently observe suggests that this is not the case.

Team appears to invest substantial dev and designer efforts into these matters. They also posted featured announcements at two largest meta sites (here and MSO, see links at the top). They even set up a survey to collect a feedback from site users.

Compared to that, addressing mentioned stats request seems to be very easy, like just a matter of a database query, or do I miss something?

Comment: I can't speak for the rest of the team, but I've seen that request for stats and it's on a rather long list of things I'd like to tackle but haven't had the time to get to it. I have a list of stats requests from various posts that I'd like to work on yours is included - just need to find the time to dig into it.

Comment: thanks @bluefeet that's understandable and that fits my thinking of it in the past, it looked totally understandable that it may be just one of those "nice to have but low priority / not very urgent things" in some long list. It only that recent focus on losing reviewers, all these announcements, changes (and especially survey) made me wonder if low priority is indeed the case

Comment: I wish I could spend more time pulling stats for these types of requests, but sometimes it becomes a rabbit hole so I need to set aside time for them. I'll see if I can find time for it soon.

Comment: @curiousdannii last time I checked [meta-tag:bump]ing was generally legitimate thing. I'd also want to point out that post you refer to is not a feature request and I can't figure what could make you misrepresent it as such, except for maybe as a way to somehow justify vote down and close

Comment: I didn't notice originally that it was on meta.SO rather than meta.SE. 
(All sites look the same on mobile.) Reposting things on meta.SE is allowed and encouraged, but in this case I'd encourage you to post it fresh, rather than just linking back.

Comment: @curiousdannii frankly I didn't intend to repost it at all, it's that recent messing around review icon, survey and so on, stuff that has leaked over from MSO to MSE made me wonder why related request for stats may look like ignored

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding on my comments above, I've seen your request for statistics and it's on a very long list of things I'd like to get to when I have time. Yes, stats requests are just digging in the database for stuff, but they also can lead into a rabbit hole of things that takes more time than initially expected.

While I'd love to spend all my time querying the database for things, we all have other priorities to work on and these requests tend to get pushed to the side until we have less on our plate. Your request isn't the only one that's missing an answer, there are many statistics requests on both [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bstatistics%5D+answers%3A0) and [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstatistics%5D+answers%3A0) that need time set aside to answer, we just don’t have enough hours in the day to [answer or comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263662/can-we-have-a-guaranteed-pipeline-for-responses-from-stack-exchange) on everything.

There has been a team working on review with the rollout of the top bar across the network, but they are not necessarily looking for statistics questions to answer. The requests for stats typically fall on the shoulders of the Community Team to answer and we just have to find time to answer them.