# Make the Stack Exchange logo in top bar more useful by having it open a menu

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, top-bar

Currently, the Stack Exchange logo in the top bar (on all sites except Stack Overflow, which has its own unique top bar) is a simple link to https://stackexchange.com/. I do not find it useful in any way, just annoying. I usually click it out of habit, and surely many new users click it without knowing where it will bring them.

To improve this, I suggest that clicking it will open a dropdown menu same as the icons to the right:

> [image]

The menu will consist of:

- [Hot Network Questions](https://stackexchange.com/)
- [All Sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questions)
- [Network Profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current)<sup>†</sup>
- [Realtime Questions](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime)

Benefits:

1. No more throwing us away from the current page when we never intended to.
2. People will actually see where they are going to.
3. Links to useful pages in stackexchange.com
4. Consistency with the behavior of other icons in the top bar.

<sub><sup>†</sup> - network profile link can be hidden for visitors who are not logged in.</sub>

Comment: I assume you are specifically talking about the logo in MSE and not StackExchange.com

Comment: @SurajRao I'm talking about the logo in the top bar which is on all sites except Stack Overflow.  StackExchange.com itself will also get it at some point, so yes it will point to itself.

Comment: But in SE it already exists as a dropdown with a list of communities

Comment: @SurajRao in SE.com it's still the old top bar, so yes, in there the logo is still the site switcher. On all other sites the switcher moved to the right, leaving the logo a static link.

Comment: Ah right..It's still the old one.

Comment: @SurajRao indeed. Same in chat and Area 51, but eventually they will all get the new top bar. :)

Comment: Consider adding the current site's tour.  A brand new user is more likely to click on the thing that looks like a logo than the thing that looks like a configuration menu (hamburger), so this seems like a good place for some welcoming guidance.

Comment: @MonicaCellio new user will have a question mark icon with the tour. I prefer the Stack Exchange logo to the left to be only about Stack Exchange, keep things organized. :)

Comment: a small issue in that image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wv1sY.png

Comment: @OptimusPrime yeah, my Paint skills are not perfect. But I believe the image gives the correct impression about what I want.

Comment: ooh, would be nice to have the help and tour there,  Maybe rather than the right side burger.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I don't think help and tour would fit there... that dropdown would be for network-wide links. Help and tour are site-specific.

Comment: @Catija thanks, that's what I think too.

Comment: [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301922/349538) suggests something similar, but I think this idea is even better.

Comment: Thanks for moving my cheese, guys.

Comment: Not quite in this form or with those links... but an on-click dropdown is in the works for the SE logo.

Comment: @Adam cheers, that is good to hear.

Comment: Something seems to have happened: When I click on the Stack Exchange logo, I'm not redirected to https://stackexchange.com but instead see a little popup with a "Visit Stack Exchange" button.

Comment: @TuringTux yup, feel free to post this as answer, with screenshot.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I've written up a quick answer (haven't had the time to take a screenshot yet, not sure when or if I'll manage it) - if you want to add one, feel equally free to do so ;)

Comment: This is just like the new disabled left-nav (I think)

Comment: @ArtemisFowl not sure what you mean.

Comment: The [new left-nav](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310908/386189), when disabled looks [like this](https://i.imgur.com/rleDuXa.jpg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the annoying link has been fixed, clicking on the Stack Exchange logo in the top bar will now display a little popup offering the option to visit Stack Exchange.

> [image: Stack Exchange logo dropdown]

See also the section "Clickable Stack Exchange Logo" in [this related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301845/new-top-bar-is-live) on MSE.

Comment: I flagged this question for a tag change and the response I got is that this current version is not likely the *final* one... it's a placeholder while they figure out what it will end up as. So they're not considering it status completed.

Comment: @Catija one year later, I'm pretty sure it's final. I am fine with that to be honest. :)