# Remove the link to stackexchange.com from the site switcher

Tags: feature-request, top-bar, stack-exchange-button

Since now there is a link to https://stackexchange.com on the logo on the left of the top bar, can we remove the link that is on the site switcher icon on the right?

The annoying part about it is that, if the page/JavaScript takes a long time to load, clicking on it will not open the site switcher but redirect to https://stackexchange.com. People don't necessarily understand what is going on. For example, a user on Ask Ubuntu [commented the following](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17394/log-out-of-the-site#comment36026_17394) when another user asked him to click on the site switcher:

> when i click on it it takes me to another site, the stack exchange home where it shows another login option, not logout. also, this reputation system is insane, this question is meta but i couldn't ask on meta because i don't have enough rep. c'mon, this is just stupid.. at least nikhil was helpful providing me a link to do it

Can we remove this link, and make the button do nothing until the page loads?

Comment: there is this proposal that might interest you.. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302475/make-the-stack-exchange-logo-in-top-bar-more-useful-by-having-it-open-a-menu