# What happened to the Stack Exchange site list?

Tags: support, top-bar, stack-exchange-button

It used to be that you could click on the Stack Exchange link on the top left of every Stack Exchange network site and would get a menu of links to other stack exchange network sites.  Now it just takes you to the main Stack Exchange site.  Why was this feature removed?

Comment: Its moved to the right with the 2017 top bar?

Comment: Oh there it is!

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302475/make-the-stack-exchange-logo-in-top-bar-more-useful-by-having-it-open-a-menu.

Answer (score 7):

It's been moved to the right now:

[image]

There's a few other changes - which I talked about on this [MSU post](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/12692/new-top-bar-is-live-what-does-it-mean-for-me). It's been active a while so slightly surprised folks just noticed.

Comment: I just noticed because the one on the left just became _inactive_ today.

Comment: @MarkAdler Inactive? I don't think so. Still links to stackexchange.com for me. The dropdown's been gone for weeks.

Comment: @Catija: Incorrect. Until today the upper left "StackExchange" link on stackexchange.com had the pull-down. Starting today it just went to stackexchange.com (where I already was).

Comment: @MarkAdler they changed it for chat and se.com yesterday but the question is about everywhere on the network... which has been changed for a while... so the only way the OP wouldn't have noticed this change is if they only ever visited those two parts of the site (or Area 51, where it remains unchanged).

Comment: As for me, I noticed the change to the other sites sometime back, but then clicking where the pull down had always been would bring me to stackexchange.com, where the pull-down _was_ still there. I had no idea why it was removed on the other sites, and was not aware of another pull-down on the far right, but I could live with the one extra step to get to the pull-down on the left and went on with my life. Until yesterday, when I was left with no pull-down, that I knew about. So that's how this can just come up the day before yesterday. It wasn't until then that we were left with no pull-down.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same thing and had no idea that there was a stack on the far right of the top bar that now does that, until I saw the comment to the question. (Which should be an answer.) I was left without my normal way of navigating between sites.

For a while anyways, when you click on StackExchange in the upper left, it should say "Hey, if you're looking for the list of StackExchange sites, try the stack icon on the far right."

Comment: If it was going to do that, why wouldn't it just contain the list itself?

Comment: Because the long-term intent is apparently to have just one pull-down list on the far right. So you would put in such a message to transition users to the non-obvious new pull-down list, when they have been using the existing one on the far left for years.