# Why has the search box background color changed?

Tags: feature-request, design, search, user-interface, top-bar

The search box in the StackExchange taskbar at the top of the page has recently changed from displaying black text on a white background to displaying pale grey text on a dark grey background. The taskbar background color is black, so there is very little contrast between the search box and the taskbar. This makes the search box much harder to see.

The search icon (magnifying glass) does not appear now until the search box is clicked on. These two changes mean that it is not obvious that the search box still exists.

These changes do not appear to be an improvement. Why have they been made? Can we have them reversed?

Comment: Because people asked for it to be changed because the high contrast was annoying. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/302017/284336

Comment: Given that the team can and does collect usage patterns I suggest we give it 6 to 8 weeks to collect data and then decide if the high-contrast search bar did attract more users.

Comment: You really think it's not obvious what the function of a box containing the words "Search on..." is?

Comment: @RobertLongson No it is not obvious that the words are in a box with a function. I have to look hard to see it. My first impression was that the box had disappeared and the search function along with it. Brilliant white against jet black might be jarring to some, but the dark grey of the box and the black of the background are almost indistinguishable. Why go from one extreme to the other?

Comment: Hard to believe, but they made the bad top bar even worse.