# Do we need two help links in the top bar?

Tags: discussion, top-bar, help-center

Last year the help button was removed from the top bar for users with review priviledge and appears in the current community menu:

> [image: help in the current community menu]

According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301902/339911) entire help section is returned to top bar for the all users now:

> [image: help for all]

Should we remove the duplicate "help" link from the current community popup or two links in the top bar are better than one?

Answer (score 4):

I think that when the redundancy is geared towards getting people to the help center... it's warranted.

Few enough people find it, so I have no issue with both of the links, particularly as the dropdown is just an icon rather than the word "help".